# Divisão matemática precisa

Tags: c, matemática, tipagem, float, ponto-flutuante

**Na calculadora Windows: 9/3,0001 = 2.999...

No meu programa: 9/3,0001 = 3;**

Gostaria de obter esse nível de precisão usando C.

Vide trechos do meu programa:

```
double op(double num1, double num2, char c)
{
      if(c == '/')
      {
        if(num2 == 0)
        {
            printf("operacao nao pode ser realizada");

            exit(1);
        }
        else
            num1 = (num1)/num2;
      }

      ...

      printf("%.3lf\n", num1);

      return num1;
}

int main()
{
   double num1,num2;

   char c;

   scanf("%lf", &num1);

   scanf("%lf", &num2);

   scanf(" %c", &c);

   num1 = op(num1, num2, c);

   ...

   return 0;
}
```

Como fazer?

Comment: O -1.#QNAN0 error é Negative Quiet Not a Number

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Se você realmente quer precisão exata para operações com ponto flutuante, terá que utilizar uma biblioteca tal qual a `GMP`. O usuário @Maniero deu uma introdução razoável sobre aonde encontrar mais informações sobre ponto flutuante (que não é um problema da linguagem C em sí, e sim do modo como ponto flutuante é implementado dentro do processador).

A biblioteca GMP, de GNU Multi-Precision Library, é uma biblioteca *open source*, para trabalhar com números com precisão arbitrária, sejam eles inteiros, fracionais ou de ponto flutuante.

É muito simples trabalhar com ela, e a documentação é bem completa, além da biblioteca estar disponível para todas as principais plataformas e arquiteturas.

Mais informações em [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Eu estava procurando ela :)

Answer (score 36):

Existem diversos *posts* sobre isto aqui no site ([esse por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)). Você não consegue fazer isto em nenhuma linguagem com número com [ponto flutuante binário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) que é o caso de `float` e `double`. Você precisa montar uma estrutura de dados ou tratar os dados de uma forma diferente. Normalmente é a forma **decimal** ou **monetária**. Comumente os números são tratados como se fossem inteiros e apresentados com casas depois da vírgula.

A precisão obtida com ponto flutuante binário tem pequenas falhas que são bem aceitas em diversas situações e trabalha com a vantagem de ser extremamente rápido. Uma das situações em que ele não pode ser usado é quando valores monetários estão sendo usados. Mas qualquer caso em que seja exigida precisão absoluta.

Não tem nada que resolva o "problema" do ponto flutuante. Pode usar um dado com muitas casas decimais de precisão que não vai resolver a questão.

- [Como formatar valores monetários com C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17613/101)
- [Valor decimal MySql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37947/101)
- [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/101)
- [Que tipo de dados (double, float ou decimal) eu deveria usar para representar moeda em .NET com C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11340/101)
- [Manipular preço em controle de estoque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10719/101)
- [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101)
- [Diferença de performance e situação de uso de tipos numéricos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9154/101)
- [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)

Em inglês (as melhores referências sobre o assunto):

- https://floating-point-gui.de/
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Essas respostas não são específicas para C mas o conceito é o mesmo para todas as linguagens porque é a forma como o processador funciona.

Qualquer outra forma só criará uma ilusão de que a divisão foi feita corretamente.

A calculadora do Windows resolve a questão na programação dela. O software entende que a precisão é necessária e lida com os dados desta forma. Curiosidade: Divida 10 por 3 e depois multiplique o resulta por 3 na calculadora do Windows. Depois limpe tudo e digite o resultado da divisão na mão. Pode por quantas casas você quiser na dízima. (3,33333333333333). A multiplicação por 3 dá resultado diferente. O software controla isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Nossa, parecia uma pergunta simples, tem um oceano por detrás.

Comment: Muito interessante, obg!

Answer (score 21):

No seu exemplo,
9/3.0001 ~ 2.99990000333322222592

Assim, a resposta arredondada a 3 casas decimais é de facto 3.000.  O seu programa está correto, dentro dos limites de precisão que especificou.  Se quiser o resultado com mais casas de precisão, deve indicá-lo no `printf`:

```C
printf("%.9lf", num1);  // com 9 casas de precisao
```

O tipo `double` tem precisão suficiente para cerca de 15 algarismos significativos (não quer dizer que sejam 15 casas decimais, depende de quantos algarismos significativos tem na parte inteira do número).  Se de facto precisar de mais do que isso, então poderá usar outro tipo de representação, como foi sugerido noutras respostas.

Para cálculo científico (em engenharia, física, outras ciências experimentais) é usual usar-se representações em vírgula flutuante (como o `double`) porque os próprios dados são geralmente imprecisos.  Assim, os resultados calculados a partir desses dados também não podem ser muito precisos.  Se tirou uma medida de comprimento usando uma régua com resolução de 1 décimo de mm, então a medida observada de 3.0001 m pode de facto ser 3.00013 m ou 3.000098.  A observação tem um erro que poderá ser de +/-0.00005 m.  Se fizer a divisão de duas medidas com essa margem de erro, também o resultado vem afetado de um erro da mesma ordem de grandeza.  Assim, não é significativo mostrar o resultado com mais algarismos significativos do que os que tem nos operandos.

Em muitas aplicações, é raro ter-se dados com mais de uma dezena de algarismos significativos, pelo que a precisão de um `double` costuma ser mais que suficiente.

Answer (score 8):

Se você *sempre* quer resultados numéricos exatos, isso é intrinsecamente impossível de se conseguir, usando computadores ou não. Por exemplo, qual o resultado "exato" da raiz quadrada de 2 ? O resultado é um número irracional, portanto não tem uma representação numérica *exata*. Existem muitos outros números assim, um número infinito na verdade. :) (Existem até mesmo números racionais de tamanho infinito, que são as dízimas periódicas.)

Especificamente quanto aos computadores, mesmo para números racionais nem sempre é possível obter uma representação númerica "exata". É só pensar em um número grande, por exemplo *1234567890[5 repetições]*. Não é possível representar este número de forma exata em uma variável `double` da linguagem C, simplemente por que não cabe em uma variável `double`...

Que eu saiba, existem (pelo menos) três maneiras de contornar parcialmente as limitações matemáticas dos computadores e linguagens atuais.

A primeira maneira é utilizar uma biblioteca matemática de "precisão infinita". Essas bibliotecas são muito utilizadas atualmente, porque são necessárias para criptografia computacional (principalmente criptografia de chave pública, usada nas "conexões seguras" em sites do tipo `https://`). Obviamente essas bibliotecas continuam tendo limitações na representação numérica de números irracionais, mas utilizam um método para armazenar números que torna possível cálculos com números "grandes", como *1234567890[5 repetições]* que citei acima, ou como as chaves de 1024 ou 2048 bits muito usadas em criptografia de chave pública.

A segunda maneira é trabalhar com biblioteca de números fracionários. Desta maneira, é possível trabalhar naturalmente com dízimas periódicas e com certos tipos de números irracionais.

A outra maneira é trabalhar com matemática simbólica, onde se utilizam símbolos para números irracionais conhecidos, como e, pi, etc. Normalmente se usa alguma aplicação específica para isso, como o "Wolfram Mathematica" (e programas open source similares), ou linguagens específicas, como (se não me engano) R, Julia, etc. Com certeza existem também bibliotecas para matemática simbólica para liguagens como C, Python, etc, é só uma questão de procurar.