# Double com precisão de no máximo 40 dígitos

Tags: c

Estou a precisar que meu programa retorne um valor alto de dígitos, na casa *de no máximo 40 dígitos*.

Vi que o tipo `DOUBLE` tem uma abrangência que vai de *1.7 X 10^-308 até 1.7X10^308*, por isso devo pensar que ele atende, até demais, minhas necessidades.

Mas quando esse simples programa é iniciado:

```
int main()
{
  double p = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.0;

  printf("%.0lf", p);

  return 0;
}
```

Ver também no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/d2Sbul)

O retorno obtido será: **1234567890123456780000000000000000**

Como contornar o problema em questão?

Comment: Você já fez esta pergunta e ela já foi respondida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38138/divis%C3%A3o-matem%C3%A1tica-precisa Ou não?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível obter esta precisão com `double`.

Números em notação de ponto fluante como o `double` são excelentes para representar números muito pequenos ou números muito grandes, mas não uma mistura dos dois. Para números muito grandes, os valores de ordem de magnitude menores influenciam muito pouco no resultado das operações, sendo descartados sem grandes perdas.

Se quiser saber mais, veja sobre o padrão [IEEE 754](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), que é o padrão que os processadores x86 implementam (acredito que ARM utiliza o mesmo padrão).

Para precisões arbitrárias é necessário utilizar uma biblioteca como a GMP (GNU Multi-Precision Library). Ela é capaz de manipular números tão grandes quanto sua memória, sejam estes números inteiros, fracionários ou de ponto flutuante.

O site da lib:

[The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/)

Ela suporta as principais plataformas (Windows, Mac, Linux, FreeBSD).

Comment: Estás respondendo pela segunda vez a mesma pergunta para o mesmo AP :-)

Comment: tenho a seguinte função: code("casa") = c*26^3 + a*26^2 + s*26^1 + a*26^0 = 35620.

Comment: para strings grandes, dá erro. preciso desses numeros para no fim utilizar numa funcao hash: x mod tam

Comment: @Caffé para você ver como não lembro nem o que almocei!

Comment: @pcccj Tenho até medo de perguntar, mas por que você precisa fazer isso? O que essa "função hash" faz? (i.e. para que ela serve?) Em geral, quando queremos trabalhar com dados de tamanho arbitrário, não convertemos esse dado em número primeiro e fazemos operações numéricas nele, esse seu requisito me parece um tanto inusitado... Poderia por favor contextualizar melhor?

Comment: Estou implementando uma Hash Table. A funcao code() irá codificar as strings. Desculpe-me a confusão.