# Problemas com alocação dinâmica

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Em um exercício preciso fazer um cadastro de uma `struct` possivelmente declarada como segue abaixo.

```
typedef struct Locatarios {
    char nomeLocatario[MAX_NOME];
    int codigoLoc;
    float valorAluguel;
} Locatarios;
```

É preciso utilizar alocação dinâmica para cadastrar um locatário por vez, então não se pergunta antes quantos serão cadastrados. Fiz assim:

```
Locatarios *pLocatarios;
pLocatarios = malloc(sizeof(Locatarios));
```

Até onde eu compreendo, a alocação funcionou perfeitamente e o cadastro está funcionando. O que eu não consigo compreender como fazer é que `codigoLoc` não pode ser repetido enquanto se faz cadastros.

Como eu percorro uma estrutura que foi alocada dinamicamente em busca de um valor?

Segue abaixo a função que realiza a pesquisa;

```
int verificaCodigo (int *codigo, int *contador) {
// Declarações locas
    Locatarios *pLocatarios;
    int aux = 0, totalLocatarios = 0;
// Instruções
    totalLocatarios = (sizeof(pLocatarios) / sizeof(pLocatarios[0]));
    pLocatarios = malloc(sizeof(Locatarios));
    if (pLocatarios != NULL) {
        for (aux = 0; aux < contador; aux++) {
            if (pLocatarios[aux].codigoLoc == codigo) {
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        }
        free(pLocatarios);
        pLocatarios = NULL;
    }
    else {
        printf("ERRO NA ALOCAÇÃO DE MEMÓRIA!");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Mostre o que já fez. Já adianto que você vai ter que guardar todos os locatários de alguma forma organizada. precisará de uma forma que você saiba onde estão todos eles, provavelmente em um *array*. Esse *array* provavelmente terá que crescer dinamicamente através de uma estrutura própria que vai alocando as partes aos poucos (como uma lista ligada) ou terá que copiar os dados para um novo *array* maior cada vez que adicionar um elemento. Ou pode otimizar isto e criar com um tamanho mínimo estabelecido e só crescer ele em momentos específicos.

Comment: Suponho que uma 'lista ligada' extrapola o conteúdo que eu posso utilizar para resolver esse exercício.
No meu primeiro teste do programa, eu pensava em após terminar o cadastro de um locatário, gravar seus dados em um arquivo, o que facilitaria a pesquisa por este código. 

O resultado de um cadastro foi este => jose ? 0x01 OS=Windows_NT Path= @ÃDŽ.

Comment: Não há problema em gravar o conteúdo em arquivo mas fazer isto só para ter acesso à lista dos locatários não faz sentido e no fundo você ainda precisaria de uma solução para formar esta lista.

Comment: Vou responder mas não poderia dar uma resposta tão completa porque não vi outras partes talvez relevantes do código. Não importa tanto, só não poderei ser mais específico. Você vai ter que se virar com a informação que vou postar.

Comment: Não acho que há partes relevantes do código. Há apenas a função cadastraLocatario() solicitando os três dados, utilizando alocação dinâmica. Mas com o que você comentou acho que tenho material suficiente para pesquisar mais e tentar resolver o problema.

Comment: Poderia ajudar ver se há outros erros, porque existem vários aí no que você postou. Estou respondendo, só me dá um tempo que eu tenho algumas outras coisas que não me deixaram concluir agora, mas posto mais tarde.

Comment: É C ou C++ ? Se for C++ você pode usar Vector<Locatarios>

Comment: @Tony Deve ser feito em C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aparentemente seu `verificaCodigo()` está no geral, no caminho certo. Tem alguns problemas no seu código como um todo que vi passando o olho:

- Não entendi porque os dois parâmetros precisem ser passados como ponteiros, acredito que seja por equívoco, se não for tem mais erros porque desta forma você está acessando o endereço da memória e não os dados que deseja (daí pode estar pegando sujeira).
- Não sei o que o `break` está fazendo ali, ele certamente não pode existir. Um `break` fora de um `if` não costuma ser útil para nada.
- Pra que está havendo uma alocação de memória em uma função que só verifica algo? Ou ela verifica algo ou ela cria o novo elemento (se é que era essa a intenção). Fazer a alocação em um lugar e deixar o preenchimento em outro agrava a desorganização.
- Se der erro de alocação na memória o retorno é 0 que é o mesmo retorno se ele não encontrar um código igual (duplicação), isto não faz sentido.
- Aparentemente você sabe quantos locatários estão cadastrados, é isto que você recebe em `contador`. Se é isto mesmo, para que calcular o `totalLocatarios` que nem está sendo usado?
- Aparentemente existem outros erros no uso de ponteiros pelas informações passadas, já que você está pegando sujeira na memória.
- Tem alguns problemas em que seu código não seria confiável mas acho que não é relevante para quem está aprendendo.
- Não é um problema mas não gosto dos nomes das variáveis que você usa, elas não indicam bem para que está servindo, chega indicar uma coisa e faz outra. Você chama o seu tipo da estrutura de `Locatarios` mas lá só cabe um locatário. O ponteiro para o *array* deles sim faz sentido no plural.
- Como é só um exercício nem vou falar do [problema de guardar um valor monetário em `float`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Provavelmente a solução mais simples para o que você deseja é fazer [realocações](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) do `pLocatarios` toda vez que for adicionar um novo elemento. Pode não ser muito eficiente mas resolve. E assim sua função de verificação de duplicidade fará sentido. Seria algo assim:

```
pLocatarios = realloc(pLocatarios, (sizeof(pLocatarios) / sizeof(pLocatarios[0]) + 1) * sizeof(pLocatarios[0]);
```

Isto está pegando a quantidade de elementos no *array*, somando 1 e alocando esta quantidade vezes o tamanho de cada elemento. Você precisará fazer esta operação anates de adicionar um novo locatário.

Se você mantem a quantidade de locatários guardada em algum lugar fica um pouco mais fácil, talvez:

```
pLocatarios = realloc(pLocatarios, (totalLocatarios + 1) * sizeof(Locatarios);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/ReallocDynamic.c).

Esta alocação deve ser feita onde vai adicionar dados do novo locatário. Na prática é possível criar um código só com o `realloc()` já que se o ponteiro inicial for `NULL` ele age exatamente igual ao `malloc`.

[Talvez nem fique muito ineficiente](https://blog.httrack.com/blog/2014/04/05/a-story-of-realloc-and-laziness/) já que o sistema operacional pode, em alguns casos, fazer otimizações na alocação que evite a cópia de dados. De qualquer forma para um exercício não importa.