# No PostgreSQL, que campo utilizar para porcentagem?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tipagem

Na tabela que estou criando, terei uma coluna que indicará o percentual de desconto, por exemplo, "para determinado convênio terei 20% de desconto, para outro convênio terei 50% de desconto", e precisarei utiliza-lo em cálculos para custo final, gostaria de saber que tipo campo devo utilizar para guardar esse percentual? Pensei em utilizar `decimal` mas fiquei na dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se não tem casas decimais pode usar o `integer` ou `smallint`, caso contrário o `decimal` é uma boa escolha. Só [não vá usar `real`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) ou algo do tipo. Acho que você já sabe que este tipo tem problemas para cálculos financeiros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O tipo real é igual ao tipo double? Que tipo de problemas ocorrem?

Comment: @AndrewAlex Quase, o `real` tem "menos precisão" mas tem o mesmo tipo de problema. Para cálculos científicos ele funciona bem mas para cálculos monetários não. Veja mais sobre o assunto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101. Veja os tipos numéricos do PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html