# Conversão de tipo dando errado

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com um problema de conversão de dados quando passa pelo `For Each`, acusa que o item `"vl_maodeobra"` não pode ser convertido de String para o tipo `Integer`. O prolema é que não importa a conversão que eu tente fazer da o mesmo erro, só mudando a mensagem, por exemplo: não pode ser convertido de `String` para `Double` ou para Decimal.

O item `"vl_maodeobra"` retorna números com virgula, decimais e a Query abaixo retorna os dados corretamente. O erro só aparece quando passa na linha `vl_mo_total += mObra.Rows("vl_maodeobra").ToString()`.

Eu estou tentando Somar o valor da mão de obra para cada linha que retornar da *query*.

```
SB = New System.Text.StringBuilder
SB.Append(" Select a.vl_maodeobra ")
SB.Append(" from garantia a ")
SB.Append(" where a.dt_exclusao is null ")
SB.Append(" and a.dt_inclusao >= to_date('01/01/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ")
SB.Append(" and a.cd_laudo = 21 ")
SB.Append(" and cd_tipo_garantia <> 'C' ")
SB.Append(" and a.vl_total > 0 ")
SB.Append(" and a.nu_lote = " & LO.ToString & " ")
SB.Append(" and a.cd_concessionario = 5 ")
Dim mObra As DataTable = DB.CreateDataTable(SB.ToString)



If mObra.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
   Dim vl_mo_total As Double = 0
   For Each currow2 As DataRow In mObra.Rows
      vl_mo_total += mObra.Rows("vl_maodeobra").ToString()
   Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta isto:

```
If mObra.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
   Dim vl_mo_total As Double = 0
   For Each currow2 As DataRow In mObra.Rows
      vl_mo_total += Convert.ToDouble(currow2("vl_maodeobra")) //esta é uma forma simplificada
   Next
End If
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/ConvertType.vb).

Pode ser que precisa de alguma adaptação na conversão dependendo do que você precisa e de como esta dado é retornado.

Mas ainda fica a questão, você trabalha com valor monetário com o tipo `Double`? Espero que tenha sido apenas um teste.

Comment: Por enquanto estou só testando, mas assim que funcionar e o cliente aprovar subirei para produção. Dessa forma funcionou, mas você não recomenda o tipo Double para valor monetário ? Porque em alguns casos passará de 100 resultados e cada resultado terá um valor diferente, podendo ser bem alto o valor.

Comment: Então use `Decimal`. `Double` é **proibitivo** para valores monetários, ele tem problemas de precisão. Ele funciona bem para cálculos científicos, mas é péssimo para valores financeiros que não pode ter diferenças de centavos. veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101 Leia tudo. Seu código pode causar problemas financeiros e até mesmo legais para a empresa.

Comment: Irei trocar para decimal. Muito Obrigado !

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas acho que se no banco de dados essa coluna não é obrigatória é necessário testar se o valor é nulo (DbNull).