# Como gerar um extrato por mês no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho que gerar um extrato no banco de dados que é parecido com o extrato bancário e apresentar o saldo acumulativo.

Tenho as seguintes colunas

```
Data, Debito, Crédito.
```

A entrada dos dados é diário mas o extrato que eu preciso é por mês.

```
01/01/2015 – Credito 100
02/01/2015 – Débido 30
02/01/2015 – credito 70
01/02/2015 – debito 50
01/02/2015 – credito 80
02/02/2015 – debito 20
01/03/2015 – credito 60
01/03/2015 – debito 20

data        debito  credito saldo
01/01/2015          100     100
02/01/2015  30              70
02/01/2015          70      140
01/02/2015  50              90
01/02/2015          80      170
01/02/2015  20              150
01/03/2015          60      210
01/03/2015  20              190
```

O resultado que deve ser:

```
data    debito  credito saldo
jan     30      170     140
fev     70      80      150
mar     20      60      190
```

Comment: Você já fez no formato sem agrupamento por mês? Posta aí como está a *query* aí fica mais fácil adaptar só a parte que você está com dúvida.

Comment: Olá não fiz nada ainda estou tentando elaborar ainda.

Comment: O Saldo não esta acumulando, ele tem que pegar o movimento aterior para gerar o novo saldo...SELECT sum(valor) as valor, sum(nfvalor) as credito, (sum(nfvalor)-sum(valor)) as saldo, mes, ano 
FROM `lc_movimento` 
WHERE idemp = '22' and (cat ='149' or cat ='170') 
GROUP BY mes, ano ORDER BY ano, mes, dia

Comment: Isto já é a resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra fazer o balanço faria assim:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
    IF(tipo = 'D', valor, '') AS debito,
    IF(tipo = 'C', valor, '') AS credito,
    (SELECT SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, -valor))
        FROM Lancamento L2
        WHERE L2.id <= Lancamento.id) AS saldo
FROM Lancamento
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQLFidle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67496/2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/MonthExt.sql).

Esta forma não é muito eficiente mas resolve. Em um sistema em produção eu pensaria em algo melhor.

Para agrupar por mês faria:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'D', valor, 0)) AS debito,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, 0)) AS credito,
    (SELECT SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, -valor)) FROM Lancamento AS L2
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Lancamento.data,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(L2.data,'%Y%m')
    ) AS saldo
FROM Lancamento
GROUP BY MONTH(data), YEAR(data)
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67496/5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/MonthExt2.sql).

Eu não confio muito nesta solução mas parece que resolve o que foi perguntado.

Eu particularmente adotaria uma solução pegando esses lançamentos e montaria o extrato no PHP. Não estou dizendo que deva fazer isto mas no meu caso específico me dou melhor com linguagens imperativas do que declarativas. Eu faria de forma mais rápida, pensando bem pouco, confiaria mais no resultado, seria mais eficiente e mais fácil de dar manutenção. Provavelmente dá para deixar melhor o código SQL mas não vou gastar mais tempo com isto.

Eu provavelmente teria uma estrutura diferente o que facilitaria a consulta.

Comment: Este é o meu problema real, o ano esta em colunas diferentes tipo: dia, mes, ano, o debito e credito também, e existe uma coluna dc para D = debito e C = credito, e tem as colunas debito e crédito, a tabela esta estruturada assim e dela preciso montar o extrato, no mysql e sua solução foi a ideal, pode me ajudar? segue o link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c6744/1/0 @bigown

Comment: Se está diferente do que está na pergunta fica complicado. Abra outra pergunta. Não garanto que poderei mexer com ela mas se der eu vejo. Coloca tudo isto. Estima as pessoas ajudarem. Dê mastigado o máximo possível e aumenta suas chances de obter resposta. Ninguém gosta de ter que fazer tudo na mão. Está no caminho certo. Você estruturou esta tabela ou pegou ela assim? Isto é um trabalho real ou exercício? Esta tabela tem uma quantidade enorme de erros.

Comment: Olá, e exatamente isto mesmo e uma tabela real, ela não esta nas formas normais, concordo mas como existe uma programação e existe dados desde 2010, estou tentando obter o extrato com ela mesmo, os seus exemplos foram muito validos e é realmente o que preciso, vou me esforçar mais na solução deste problema. obrigado pelos exemplos  conseguindo o resultado desejado vou publicar. @bigown

Answer (score 1):

Consegui o resultado espera, minha tabela não esta nas formas normais, mas iria ser muito oneroso ter que reprogramar.

segue o link do resultado esperado.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1f43/6)

```
SELECT dia, mes, ano, credito, debito, format(saldo,2) as saldo
FROM (
    SELECT
        dia,
        mes,
        ano,
        credito,
        debito,
    @dc := dc AS tipo,
    @saldo := IF(@dc = 'C', @saldo + credito, @saldo - debito) AS saldo
    FROM lc_movimento, (SELECT @dc := 'C', @saldo := 0) as vars
    ORDER BY ano, mes, dia
) AS extrato
```

Comment: Na verdade a tabela tem vários problemas, a normalização é o menor deles. Provavelmente o mais grave é usar `double` para armazenar valores monetários. Isto é impreciso e pode causar prejuízos. Pode até gerar um processo contra a empresa. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101