# Soma do lote de cheques, valor total e validação

Tags: c, validação

> Escreva um programa em C para validar um lote de cheques. O programa deverá inicialmente solicitar a soma do lote e o número de cheques. A seguir deverá ler o valor de cada cheque calculando a soma total. Após a digitação de todos os cheques o programa deverá imprimir as seguintes mensagens: LOTE Ok se a soma informada for igual a soma calculada.Diferença negativa se a soma calculada for menor que a informada. Diferença positiva se a soma calculada for maior que a informada. Observação: O valor da diferença deve ser impresso (caso exista).

Segue o código feito até agora.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int somaLote, aux;
    float somaCheques, somaTotal;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de cheques: ");
    scanf("%d", somaLote);

    for(aux=0; aux<=somaLote; aux++)
    {
        printf("Insira o valor do cheque: ");
        scanf("%f", &somaCheques);
        somaTotal = somaTotal + somaCheques;
    }
    printf("Soma total dos cheques: %d", somaLote);
    printf("Valor total dos cheques: %f", somaTotal);
}
```

O compilador trava e fica dando erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros e está incompleto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int  main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int qtde, aux;
    float valorCheque, valorTotal = 0, totalLote;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de cheques: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtde);
    printf("Digite a soma do lote: ");
    scanf("%f", &totalLote);
    for (aux = 0; aux < qtde; aux++) {
        printf("Insira o valor do cheque: ");
        scanf("%f", &valorCheque);
        valorTotal += valorCheque;
    }
    printf("Soma total dos cheques: %f", totalLote);
    printf("Valor total dos cheques: %f", valorTotal);
    if (totalLote == valorTotal) printf("Lote ok");
    else if (totalLote > valorTotal) printf("Diferença negativa");
    else printf("Diferença positiva");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/aXzrGU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wklnqici-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumValidation.c).

Eu mudei os nomes das variáveis para ficar mais claro o que cada uma faz. Provavelmente a confusão já começou aí. O código usou uma variável que era para controlar a quantidade de cheques como o controle do total do lote. Quem sequer foi pedido conforme o enunciado diz. E isto gerava uma série de erros.

O `scanf` estava passando um valor como argumento, quando na verdade deveria passar um endereço de memória. Então faltou o operador `&`.

Obviamente a verificação se o lote está ok nem estava feita.

Nem vou falar que [`float` não pode ser usado para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101) porque isto é apenas um exercício.

Comment: Não acho que o correto seja dar a resposta do algoritmo, já que é um exercício, onde o intuito é fazer com que ele treine a linguagem.

Comment: A pergunta pede isto. E ele não pediu pronto, pediu para resolvermos o problema de lógica dele. Tem vários erros no código, resolver um não adianta nada.

Comment: Ms o resto faz parte da pergunta, não só esta frase. Se levar ao pé da letra só o que está com interrogação como pergunta, então a resposta, é "Sim".

Comment: O que foi pedido foi a solução do "compilador travar e ficar dando erro", o que foi gerado pelo scanf sem o &, montar toda a lógica e fazer o exercício creio que foge um pouco. Sendo que o que foi pedido era q "analisássemos" o código atrás do erro que faz o compilador travar.

Comment: Depois ele decide qual resposta é melhor pra ele.

Answer (score 3):

O erro está aqui:

```
printf("Digite a quantidade de cheques: ");
scanf("%d", somaLote);
```

onde o correto seria:

```
printf("Digite a quantidade de cheques: ");
scanf("%d", &somaLote);
```

Para armazenar algo é obrigatório o uso do & antes do nome da varável.

Comment: Que erro mais bobo que eu fiz alí ein hahaha, obrigado cara!