# Como limitar casas decimais?

Tags: c, c++, formatação

Estou com uma dúvida, tem como limitar o número de casas decimais em C++?

```
float x = 2.958;
```

Em vez de arredondar para cima ou para baixo usando `floorf()`, `roundf()`, tem como pegar só os dois números depois da vírgula?

que ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
float x = 2.95;
```

Comment: Você pode limitar na hora de imprimir, é isso ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma das formas seria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float num = 3.14159;
    cout << fixed;
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << num << endl;
    printf("%.2f", num); //apenas se for usar em C puro, não use em C++
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3m6LNU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hqjhpxei-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/FormatDecimalPlaces.cpp).

Comment: Exibir na tela eu até consigo, o problema é no hora de passa esse valor para uma variável.

Comment: Com `float` você não pode limitar a quantidade de casas decimais. Você pode até tentar fazer arredondamento, mas isto não dá certo por causa da forma como ele é armazenado. Ele é binário e não decimal, então sempre poderá um valor inesperado e número de casas indefinido. Você só pode controlar a quantidade de casas na apresentação. Se precisa controlar o número de casas decimais no valor, não pode usar `float`.

Comment: entendi, outro tipo de variável poderia funcionar tipo double?

Comment: Não, o `double` tem o mesmo problema, tem que usar um tipo decimal ou criar um mecanismo próprio. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101

Answer (score 5):

Você pode conseguir o valor esperado utilizando a função `floorf()`, assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    float x = 2.958;
    cout << floorf(x * 100) / 100;
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KM50ad)