# Como limitar casa decimais?

Tags: c, arredondamento

```
printf("%.3f", &resp);
```

Estou usando a seguinte linha, porém, ao comparar com um número, ele exige que tenha o mesmo número de casa decimais do originais, por exemplo:

```
2.963258741 !=  2.963
```

**Tem como limitar as casas para que essa comparação seja verdadeira?**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como limitar casas decimais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94564/como-limitar-casas-decimais)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Tem, mas não da forma como espera. Está usando [tipos de ponto flutuante binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), e comparações são complicadas. Se depende de exatidão, precisa usar um tipo de ponto fixo ou flutuante decimal. Como C não tem nativo precisa [criar uma solução ou arrumar uma biblioteca de terceiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Uma possibilidade "mais simples" é transformar isto em inteiro para comparar. Você pode multiplicar por 1000 para obter as 3 casas que deseja e fazer um *cast* para `int`. Ainda não é o ideal porque pode ter problemas de arredondamento, para ser exato teria que tratar isto.

Uma possibilidade sem usar um tipo decimal é pedir para entrar com o valor sem a vírgula, aí cabe em um inteiro.

Só note que se for manipular inteiros tem que entender a escala, para soma e subtração é tranquilo, mas para multiplicação e divisão muda o número de casas e aí precisa voltar para o número de casas original. Por isso um tipo decimal pode ser o mais adequado, ele já trata isto (ainda que nem sempre do jeito que precisa, aí volta ser manual).

Tem uma maneira de fazer a [comparação de `float` com aproximação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108998/101), mas eu não gosto dela. Obviamente precisa cuidar da escala também.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).