# BigDecimal erro cannot find symbol

Tags: java, decimal

Dado uma quantia em R$ convertê-lo em dólar.

Bem, baseado neste contexto o professor solicitou que utilizarmos o paradigma orientação a objeto. Antes devo elucidar que utilizo para fim a ide BlueJ para resolver o problema, segundo meu professor ele é melhor para fins didáticos, criei uma classe `Cambio` e uma classe `Main`, aquela está locado os métodos que recebe a quantia, a taxa cambial e a conversão,  esta inicializa sistema por assim dizer contido o método `main`.

classe Cambio:

```
public class Cambio
{
    private float amount;
    private double conversion;
    private float exchange;

    /**
     * Construtor
     */
    public Cambio(float amount, float exchange)
    {
        setAmount(amount);
        setExchange(exchange);
        conversion = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Método modificador: quantia.
     */
    public void setAmount(float amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    /**
     * Método modificador: taxa.
     */
    public void setExchange(float exchange)
    {
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo acessador: quantia
     */
    public float getAmount()
    {
        return this.amount;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo acessador: taxa
     */
    public float getExchange()
    {
        return this.exchange;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo modificador: calcula o cambio.
     */
    public double getConversion()
    {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

        conversion = (float)this.amount / (float)this.exchange;

        return df.doubleValue(conversion);
    }
}
```

Classe main:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Digite a quantia: ");
        float amount = read.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Digite a taxa cambial: ");
        float exchange = read.nextFloat();

        Cambio cb = new Cambio(amount, exchange);

        System.out.println("A valor em dolar: USS$" + cb.getConversion());
    }
}
```

Estou utilizando a classe para formatar os valores o `BigDecimal`. Dá um erro e não compila:

> cannot find symbol (class BigDecimal)

Na linha:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Até onde eu compreendo lendo a documentação do BlueJ eu estou chamando um objeto que não existe. Eu já utilizei o `BigDecimal` para formatar valores em `double` em outro exercício.

Comment: Não tem mais nada no seu código? Que linha dá o erro? Mostre a linha, não adianta falar o número.

Comment: Não todo código é esse, a linha que dá erro é 62 (BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código usa uma variável chamada `d` na linha

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

essa variável não é declarada em lugar algum do código. Certamente isso causa o problema. Tem que ver o que quer usar aí. Se o método deve receber um parâmetro ou se deve pegar um membro da classe.

Na linha

```
df.doubleValue(conversion);
```

tem outra variável não declarada em uso. Talvez neste caso era para ser `bd` no lugar de `df`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Variable.java).

Trabalhar com [`float` e `double` para valor monetário não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). Mas este é outro problema.

Jogar códigos aleatórios também não funciona. O código precisa fazer algum sentido, precisa ter um mínimo de coerência com o que existe.

Comment: Bom segundo documentação não precisava mas, importei sim quando deu o primeiro erro, utilizei da maneira que vc mencionou, realmente eu me confundi no df ( por db) mas, no código já havia corrigido isso... a respeito da variável d poderia me explicar um pouco mais, segundo o tutorial que eu li na internet ele menciona esta linha desta maneira.

Comment: Sim, no contexto desse tutorial, agora você está fazendo outra coisa. Você tem que descobrir o que você quer usar como número decimal. Seria o `amount`? É o que eu falei não adianta copiar e colar um código que você achou. Isto não é programar. Tem que escrever cada pedaço de código com algum sentido, tem que saber porque cada parte está ali. Sem saber isto, nada vai dar certo. Provavelmente precisa estudar programação no sentido geral antes de começar fazer códigos. Programar não é copiar receita de bolo. E adoraria conhecer a documentação que diz que não precisa importar algo necessário.

Comment: Referente a documentação, é do próprio BlueJ - de fato eu ainda estou aprendendo a programar.  Sem sair do mérito da pergunta, eu construí baseado no meu conhecimento, é não gostei do jeito que estava sendo imprimido e busquei mais conhecimento, afim de melhorar meu algoritmo, bom a qual eu gostaria de formatar é a variável "conversion" eu editei a pergunta, falhei na hora de digitar o código na pergunta

Comment: Bom enfim, deixar para receber essa instrução para manipular dados ou formatar dados quando os professores acharem que é necessário.