# Cálculo de porcentagem em C

Tags: c, matemática

> " Codifique, compile e execute um programa em C que receba o
>   salário-base de um funcionário, calcule e mostre o salário a receber,
>   sabendo-se que esse funcionário tem gratificação de 5% sobre o
>   salário-base, e paga imposto de 7% sobre o salário-base. "

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float salario,s1,s2,final;

    printf("Digite o salario: ");
    scanf("%f",&salario);

    s1=(salario*0.07)/100;
    s2=(salario*0.05)/100;
    final=s2-s1;


    printf("O salario com desconto: %f",final);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, além de postar o código deixe claro na pergunta qual o problema que você encontrou e o que você já tentou fazer.

Comment: Vlw, o bigown já me ajudou !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro erro é que está aplicando o desconto antes de dar o bônus, que é o contrário do que o enunciado determina.

Segundo que está calculando porcentagem errado mesmo. Está achando o percentual a ser aplicado, dividindo por 100, não sei porque, e não está aplicando ao total.

Como tanto o bônus, como o desconto deve ser dado em cima do salário base, fica fácil fazer a conta. A fórmula precisa pegar o valor total que é o seu 100%, então vamos normalizá-lo para 1 (daí vem a divisão por 100 que estava usando, você já faz ela antes de colocar no código). Depois normalizamos para 1 os percentuais, ou seja 5%, vira 0,05 (dividido por 100 novamente) e 7% vira 0,07. Então somamos o total (1) com o bônus (0,05) e subtraímos o desconto (0,07). Olha que fórmula simples.

Se quiser visualizar com a divisão:

```
salario = salario * (100 / 100 + 5 / 100 - 7 / 100)
```

Obviamente podemos simplificar isto. Já simplifiquei no código abaixo. No teste feito no ideone eu já fiz toda a conta.

Por fim, está usando variáveis demais. Não é um erro, mas é desnecessário.

Em um código real várias coisas poderiam ser feitas de forma diferente. Não vou falar que o tipo [`float` não é adequado para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float salario;
    printf("Digite o salario: ");
    scanf("%f", &salario);
    salario *= 1 + 0.05 - 0.07;
    printf("\nO salario com desconto: %f", salario);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JYsT8I). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yfudlavh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Percent.c).

Comment: Por mais pessoas como você eu voto sim (:

Comment: Eu dei uma simplificada ainda maior no ideone. Preferi não fazer isto inicialmente para você entender o processo, mas poderia ser mais simples.

Comment: Luan, lembra que eu te perguntei (na versão anterior desta pergunta) se a sua dúvida era de mátemática ou de programação? Você havia respondido que era de programação, mas agora se confirma que é mesmo de matemática. Não estou comentando por mal, apenas pra vc perceber isso e focar seu estudo naquilo que é de fato a sua maior dificuldade. :) Assim, sugiro aproveitar a boa resposta que teve e fazer exercícios alternativos (com outros problemas similares mesmo).

Comment: @LuizVieira de fato não tinha me atentado a este detalhe, fui na intuição quando estava fazendo, já que o imposto não pode ser sobre o salário base, mas quem sou eu pra dizer que o exercício é que tá errado... :D Melhorado.

Comment: Vw a todos que responderam, vou procurar mais pra fazer não quero ficar parado num ponto haha.

Comment: Na próxima dúvida não se limite a colar código, detalhe a sua dificuldade/problema, pois pode ser a mesma que outro utilizador do SO. @Maniero o salvador \o/ hehehe