# Como decidir o tipo de uma função?

Tags: c, funções, tipagem

Em muitos códigos escritos C em que eu vejo na internet eu só vejo funções do tipo `void` e `int` e possível declarar funções de outros tipos? Por exemplo `struct` e `float`.

Eu fiz um teste simples com os tipos `char` e `float` e funcionou, mas eu ainda não entende a verdadeira importância do tipo da função quando eu devo usar qual?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float rf(){

    float testfloat = 1.3;
    char string['C'];
    printf("'%f' '%s'", testfloat, string);

}

char rc(){

    float testfloat = 1.3;
    char string['C'];
    printf("'%f' '%s'", testfloat, string);

}

int main(){

 rf();
 rc();
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Você pode declarar funções que retornam qualquer tipo de dados. Só que acho que você não entendeu muito bem o que é retorno na função, já que suas função não retornam nada.

Comment: as funcoes retornan o que esta contido nelas @JoãoSobral

Comment: @Assanges a unica função do seu exemplo que retorna algo (no caso `0`) é o main. O resto não tá retornando nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na verdade a função não tem tipo, quem tem tipo é o valor que ela retorna. Isso sim é importante.

O retorno, assim como os parâmetros, variáveis, constantes, etc. podem e devem ter qualquer tipo disponível no código, pode ser um já definido na linguagem, na bibliotecas padrão, em outras bibliotecas que esteja usando, ou tipos definidos pelo seu código (com `typedef` e provavelmente `struct`).

Obviamente que a função deve retornar algo com o comando `return` e o valor retornado deve ser compatível com o tipo de retorno declarado nela.

Se for pra retornar nada, então o tipo de retorno deve ser `void`. Assim a função não poderá ser usada em expressões que sempre esperam algum valor. `void` é nenhum valor, é "menos" do que nulo.

Você deve usar o que seja mais adequado para resolver o problema. Nenhuma resposta genérica poderá determinar qual é o mais adequado para a situação específica.

É claro que algumas coisas a gente sabe. Um tipo deve comportar todos os valores válidos que sabe que aquele elemento do código pode ter. Por exemplo, se declarar um `int`, provavelmente (depende de arquitetura), o maior valor possível é 2.147.483.647.

Em alguns raros casos pode precisar de um tipo não sinalizado (que só aceita positivos), é raro e não vem ao caso aqui porque não deve optar por eles como padrão.

Se precisa de um valor monetário o programador novato vai quente no `float` ou `double` (que permitem valores com parte decimal), mas [não pode usá-los para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Enfim, são só exemplos, não dá para colocar todas regras básicas sob pena da pergunta ficar muito ampla.

O exemplo ligeiramente melhorado de acordo com minha especulação:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float rf() {
    float testfloat = 1.3;
    char string['C'];
    printf("'%f' '%s'", testfloat, string);
    return testfloat;
}

char rc() {
    float testfloat = 1.3;
    char string[]; //havia um erro aqui e isso ainda não vai dar certo
    printf("'%f' '%s'", testfloat, string);
    return 'a';
}

void rv() {
    printf("faz algo aqui");
    return;
}
int main() {
    float x = rf();
    char c = rc();
    rv();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ReturnType.c).

Comment: no caso se eu implimentar uma funcao que retorne uma struct eu poderia criar uma especie de classe bacana gostei +1  pela resposta