# Escala de precisão usando Entity Framework e SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, valor-monetário

Tem algum tempo que venho notando, algo estranho ao salvar valores `double` na base de dados SQL Server com o Entity Framework.

Notei que ao informar um valor ex: 12.23 após gravar a informação está quebrando os decimais em mais casas ex: 12.22501.

Isso não ocorre com frequência e nem todas as vezes que um valor é gravado, e também não tem impacto nos cálculos (pois não uso `round`).

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Por que isso ocorre?
- Alguém já passou por isso? como resolveu?
- É configuração ou depende do tipo de banco de dados?

A estrutura que utilizo é a informada abaixo:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double MyClass { get; set; };
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClass;
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(x => x.ValorTeste).HasPrecision(16, 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Por que isso ocorre?

Porque o valor gravado em `double` é usado para cálculos científicos onde precisa performance e o processador tem instruções especializadas que fazem os cálculos muito rapidamente. Como ele é todo feito de forma binária e não decimal, como estamos acostumados, ele consegue velocidade e precisão grande, mas não consegue exatidão em muitas situações. Para a ciência, computação gráfica e coisas do tipo, geralmente isso não é problema. Para uso financeiro é um enorme problema.

> Alguém já passou por isso? como resolveu? É configuração ou depende do tipo de banco de dados?

Todo programador que usou `double` onde não podia já passou por isso e teve prejuízos. A solução é usar o tipo correto para a necessidade, ou [`decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) (existente no .NET e SQL Server) ou [`money`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) (só existente no SQL Server precisando um mapeamento feito pelo Entity Framework).

Com o tipo certo nada precisa ser configurado.

Note que o que será apresentado ainda dependa de formatação específica, mas apresentação é diferente do valor em si. Cálculos ainda podem precisar de arredondamentos e adaptações, mas todos trabalharão corretamente com centavos ou outras partes decimais de um número.

A performance pode não ser magnífica, mas ainda é ótima para esse tipo de aplicação. Nem se comparara, por exemplo com um texto que é absurdamente mais lento na maioria das situações.

Não há solução enquanto usar `double`. Qualquer outra tentativa de fazer o `double` se comportar com exatidão falhará. O pior é que em alguns casos poderá funcionar e o programador achar que deu certo. Muito programador acredita piamente que é possível usar `double` com exatidão, apesar de ser bem comprovado que não.

Mais informações em [outra pergunta aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). E veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).