# Como limitar as casas decimais da leitura ("scanf()") de uma variável double?

Tags: c, scanf, double

O exercício pede que as leituras das variáveis `double` sejam limitadas em apenas uma casa decimal cada uma delas. Eu tentei colocar `"%.1lf"` no `scanf()`, assim como usamos no `printf()`, mas não funcionou.

Como poderia solucionar isto?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     
    double A, B, MEDIA;

    do{
          printf("Digite A: ");
          scanf("%lf", &A);

    }while(A<0 || A>10);

    do{
          printf("Digite B: ");
          scanf("%lf", &B);

    }while(B<0 || B>10);


    MEDIA=(A+B)/2;

    printf("MEDIA = %.5lf\n", MEDIA);
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 11):

Não tem como fazer isso. O `scanf()` é útil para leituras bem básicas. Se precisa de algo mais complexo precisa escrever uma função mais sofisticada ou usar alguma biblioteca que forneça algo melhor. Em aplicações reais é comum os programadores terem algo assim à mão.

Sequer dá para limitar a quantidade de casas decimais usando um `double` já que a representação dele é binária. É possível fazer algum cálculo (multiplica por 10, pega a parte inteira e divide por 10) para arredondar valores (mas [sem exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101)). Isso não é o mesmo que limitar.

Outra possibilidade é trabalhar com inteiros, o que dificulta um pouco a digitação porque se a nota for 7.5 teria que digitar 75, depois resolver a vírgula na apresentação (de certa forma facilita porque não tem mais que digitar o ponto, mas é menos intuitivo para a pessoa, tem que deixar bem claro que é assim que precisa digitar, a pessoa pode demorar para acostumar, principalmente porque nota 7 deve ser digitado como 70 (dá para validar para alertar se a nota fora inferior a 10, improvável a pessoa ter essa nota e ser erro de digitação).

Ainda poderia ler como texto, converter para inteiro. Isso facilitaria a experiência do usuário, mas dificultaria o desenvolvimento. De certa forma cai na primeira alternativa de fazer uma função sofisticada de leitura de dados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).