# Como converter Float para String usando LINQ para entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, query, linq, linq-to-entities

Como converter Float para String usando LINQ para entity?

Preciso converter um campo do meu banco de dados que tem o **tipo float** para o **tipo string no meu C#** usando o LINQ.

Tente usar o Convert.ToString,

```
 ChaveArquivo = Convert.ToString(n.scanIma.Imagem),
```

mas isso gera a seguinte *query* no SQL.

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [t0].[Imagem], 2)
```

retornando o valor *8.125000000000000e+003*, sendo que no bando o valor original é **8125**, quero converte para *string* com o mesmo valor **"8125"**.

Isso é possível fazer direto no banco de dados com  a função  `Str( [t0].[Imagem])`.

Preciso de uma equivalente no LINQ.

Minha consulta;

```
using (var dm = DataContextFactory.GetContext(pacoteUsuario.Usuario))
{
    var consulta = (from docsCol in dm.Tabela_DocsColetivas
                    join doc in dm.Tabela_Documentos on docsCol.Apol_coletiva equals doc.Apol_coletiva
                    join scanIma in dm.Tabela_ScanImagens on new { Documento = doc.Documento, Alteracao = doc.Alteracao } equals new { Documento = scanIma.Documento.GetValueOrDefault(), Alteracao = scanIma.Alteracao.GetValueOrDefault() }
                    join tip in dm.Tabela_TiposImagens on scanIma.Cod_tipoimg equals tip.Cod_tipoimg into ti
                    from tipImag in ti.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join ProdSubs in dm.Tabela_ProdutosSubs on doc.Cod_sub equals ProdSubs.Cod_sub into ps
                    from ProdSub in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        scanIma,
                        doc,
                        tipImag,
                        docsCol,
                        ProdSub,
                    })
                    .AsQueryable();

    var arquivos = consulta
        .Select(n => new ListaArquivos
        {
            NumeroContrato = n.docsCol.Apolice,
            NumeroApolice = n.doc.Apolice,
            NumeroFatura = n.doc.Endosso,
            CodSubGrupo = n.ProdSub.Cod_sub,
            NomeSubGrupo = n.ProdSub.Descricao,
            Competencia = String.Concat(n.doc.Mes_producao, "/", n.doc.Ano_producao),
            DescrArquivo = n.scanIma.Descricao,
            TipoImagem = Convert.ToDouble(n.tipImag.Tipo_uso),
            DescrTipoImagem = n.tipImag.Descricao == null ? string.Empty : n.tipImag.Descricao,
            ChaveArquivo = Convert.ToString(n.scanIma.Imagem),
        });

    this.listaArquivos.AddRange(arquivos.ToList());
    listArquivos.Add(this);
    return listArquivos;
}
```

Classe ListaArquivos

```
namespace SistemasSeguros.COL.View.Webservice.Parâmetros
{
    public class ListaArquivos
    {
        public string NumeroContrato { get; set; }
        public string NumeroApolice { get; set; }
        public string NumeroFatura { get; set; }
        public double? CodSubGrupo { get; set; }
        public string NomeSubGrupo { get; set; }
        public string Competencia { get; set; }
        public string DescrArquivo { get; set; }
        public double? TipoImagem { get; set; }
        public string DescrTipoImagem { get; set; }
        public string ChaveArquivo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: O valor no banco é somente 8125?

Comment: Não, esse é apenas o primeiro valor desse campo na tabela scanIma.

Comment: Teria como colocar o valor completo?

Comment: @Randrade, esse valor é o valor real que esta na primeira linha dessa coluna, existe mais colunas com valores diferentes, mas para essa coluna /linha o valor é somente esse, sempre são valores inteiros, mas o campo foi criado com float.

Comment: Não é bem isso. Quero dizer que ficou confuso. Você diz que retorna o valor **8.125000000000000e+003**, mas está fazendo a conversão de qual valor para chegar nesse? Pergunto isso pois existem várias formas de fazer essa conversão, e até o `CultureInfo` pode influenciar. Mas sem saber o valor original, fica um poco mais difícil ver o que realmente aconteceu.

Comment: Acho que seria mais simples se especificasse o valor original, como está fazendo a conversão (você já disse `ChaveArquivo = Convert.ToString(n.scanIma.Imagem)`) e o valor esperado (que também disse que é **8125**)

Comment: editei a pergunta,

Comment: Tenho a resposta a baixo, mas espero algo mais conveniente, ou seja uma unica função que faça o convert para o tipo esperado.

Comment: Dá para fazer algumas gambiarras para resolver, mas a solução é mudar o tipo e nem sempre vai funcionar como espera. `float` não tem exatidão. Porque não pode ser a conversão e tem que ser o `Str()`?

Comment: @bigown, não necessariamente tem que ser Str(), mas uma função que seja capaz de converter o float para string. FUNÇÃO GERADA PELO ENTITY  FRAMEWORK. como falei na pergunta o Convert.ToString() lança no banco o CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [t0].[Imagem], 2) esse dois no final e o que esta gerando o número 8.125000000000000e+003.

Comment: @Randrade, agora que entendi o sentido da [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154297/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-linq-equivalente-ao-str-do-sql-server/154340#comment318519_154297), a resposta é sim, esse 8125 é o número real que esta no banco e complementando o campo é sempre um valor inteiro, porem o ZÉ que criou a tabela teve a audácia de usar um FLOAT, para um campo PK.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod eu acho que a minha resposta faz o que deseja. E falo do erro de exatidão.

Comment: Gostaria de sabe o porque do -1, para que possar melhorar a pergunta,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dá para usar a [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_StringConvert_System_Nullable_System_Double__), ela será convertida para o código adequado em SQL:

```
ChaveArquivo = StringConvert(n.scanIma.Imagem)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/StringConvert.cs).

Isso responde a pergunta diretamente. Mas não resolve o problema mostrado nos comentários.

O problema é que o tipo `float` não tem capacidade de dar exatidão. Já [respondi sobre isso em diversas perguntas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). O problema não pode ser resolvido de outra forma. E o pior é que parece que resolve em alguns casos. Isso é um perigo porque causa a sensação de segurança que não existe. Claro que pode ser que só vá ser usado em situações que gambiarras resolvam. Mas não é possível resolver todos casos. Se a informação exata não está disponível não tem como garantir que obterá ela, não importa que algoritmo use.

Comment: Conforme a documentação indica o *namespace* é `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` que está no *assembly* `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: Bom, aí eu não sei como está usando. Na documentação não consta essa exceção como uma possível, então o problema deve estar em outro lugar.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod Você adicionou a DLL `System.Data.Entity`? Ela geralmente fica em **C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0** ou no EF6

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema usando duas conversões uma para ToInt64 e outra para ToString.

```
var arquivos = consulta
            .Select(n => new ListaArquivos
            {
                NumeroContrato = n.docsCol.Apolice,
                NumeroApolice = n.doc.Apolice,
                CodSubGrupo = n.ProdutosSub.Cod_sub,
                NomeSubGrupo = n.ProdutosSub.Descricao,
                Competencia = n.doc.Mes_producao + '/' + n.doc.Ano_producao,
                DescrArquivo = n.scanIma.Descricao,
                TipoImagem = Convert.ToDouble(n.tipoImag.Tipo_uso),
                DescrTipoImagem = n.tipoImag.Descricao,
                ChaveArquivo = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(n.scanIma.Imagem)),
            });
```