# Como eu poderia inserir as structs em uma lista?

Tags: c, c++, struct

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct FICHA_INSCRICAO
{
    char nome[50];
    char cpf[10];
    char logradouro[100];
    char bairro[20];
    char cidade[20];
    char estado[1];
    char email[50];
    char telefone[10];
    double salario_familiar = 0;
    int pessoas_quant = 0;
    double renda_percapita = 0;

    void INSERE() {

        cout << "Nome: ";
        cin >> nome;
        cout << "CPF: ";
        cin >> cpf;
        cout << "Logradouro: ";
        cin >> logradouro;
        cout << "Bairro: ";
        cin >> bairro;
        cout << "Cidade: ";
        cin >> cidade;
        cout << "Estado: ";
        cin >> estado;
        cout << "Email: ";
        cin >> email;
        cout << "Telefone: ";
        cin >> telefone;
        cout << "Salario Total da Familia: ";
        cin >> salario_familiar;
        cout << "Quantidade de pessoas na sua casa: ";
        cin >> pessoas_quant;

        renda_percapita = salario_familiar / pessoas_quant;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int op = 1, tamanho = 0;
    FICHA_INSCRICAO *ficha = new FICHA_INSCRICAO[tamanho];

    while (op == 1)
    {
        ficha[tamanho].INSERE();
        tamanho++;

        cout << "\nNovo cadastro?\n"
            << "1 - SIM\n"
            << "0 - NAO\n";
        cin >> op;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de lista? Qual seu problema? Precisa fazer usando funcionalidades do C? Não pode fazer só usando o que é específico do C++?

Comment: So em c++, quero atribuir a struct a uma lista linear sequencial, organizada pelos nomes em ordem alfabetica.

Comment: Pelo que está falando acho que deve usar um [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas para complementar, este é o mesmo fonte criado pelo @Maniero, mas com duas coisas que acho legais: *smart pointers*, e uso de operação "move" ao invés de copiar o objeto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class FichaInscricao
{
   public:
      string Nome;
      string Cpf;
      string Logradouro;
      string Bairro;
      string Cidade;
      string Estado;
      string Email;
      string Telefone;
      double SalarioFamiliar = 0;
      int QuantidadePessoas = 0;
      double RendaPerCapita = 0;
};

int main()
{
   // mapa de smart pointers
   map<string, unique_ptr<FichaInscricao>> fichario;

   int op;

   do
   {
      // cria no heap uma instancia da classe FichaInscricao,
      // e guarda o endereco em um smart pointer
      auto ficha = make_unique<FichaInscricao>(); // COOL!
      ficha->Inserir();

      // move o endereco de dentro do smart pointer para dentro do mapa
      fichario[ficha->Nome] = std::move(ficha); // COOL!

      cout << "\nNovo cadastro?\n"
           << "1 - SIM\n"
           << "0 - NAO\n";
      cin >> op;
   } while (op == 1);

   for (const auto& ficha: fichario)
   {
      cout << ficha.first << " => " << ficha.second->Cpf << '\n';
   }

}

void FichaInscricao::Inserir()
{
   cout << "Nome: ";
   cin >> Nome;
   cout << "CPF: ";
   cin >> Cpf;
   cout << "Logradouro: ";
   cin >> Logradouro;
   cout << "Bairro: ";
   cin >> Bairro;
   cout << "Cidade: ";
   cin >> Cidade;
   cout << "Estado: ";
   cin >> Estado;
   cout << "Email: ";
   cin >> Email;
   cout << "Telefone: ";
   cin >> Telefone;
   cout << "Salario Total da Familia: ";
   cin >> SalarioFamiliar;
   cout << "Quantidade de pessoas na sua casa: ";
   cin >> QuantidadePessoas;
   RendaPerCapita = SalarioFamiliar / QuantidadePessoas;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu vou refazer o código para C++ sem usar o que é estilo C.

O adequado é usar um [mapa](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), pleo que foi descrito como requisito. Se o requisito estiver errado aí a solução seria outra.

Mudei para classe porque é mais idiomático para este tipo de uso em C++. Usei `string` no lugar de *array* de `char` que é coisa de C. Usei nomes melhores.

Não gosto desse `Inserir()` na classe, mas para um exercício está bom. Também [não deveria usar `double` para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Tem outros pequenos problemas que não são graves para um exercício.

Mandei imprimir no final e testei com dados fora de ordem para mostrar que está em ordem alfabética.

Provavelmente há uma solução mais complexa que seja melhor que isto que tem suas dificuldades próprias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class FichaInscricao {
public:
    string Nome;
    string Cpf;
    string Logradouro;
    string Bairro;
    string Cidade;
    string Estado;
    string Email;
    string Telefone;
    double SalarioFamiliar = 0;
    int QuantidadePessoas = 0;
    double RendaPerCapita = 0;

    void Inserir() {
        cout << "Nome: ";
        cin >> Nome;
        cout << "CPF: ";
        cin >> Cpf;
        cout << "Logradouro: ";
        cin >> Logradouro;
        cout << "Bairro: ";
        cin >> Bairro;
        cout << "Cidade: ";
        cin >> Cidade;
        cout << "Estado: ";
        cin >> Estado;
        cout << "Email: ";
        cin >> Email;
        cout << "Telefone: ";
        cin >> Telefone;
        cout << "Salario Total da Familia: ";
        cin >> SalarioFamiliar;
        cout << "Quantidade de pessoas na sua casa: ";
        cin >> QuantidadePessoas;
        RendaPerCapita = SalarioFamiliar / QuantidadePessoas;
    }
};

int main() {
    map<string, FichaInscricao> fichario;
    int op = 1;
    while (op == 1)  {
        FichaInscricao ficha;
        ficha.Inserir();
        fichario.emplace(ficha.Nome, ficha);
        cout << "\nNovo cadastro?\n"
             << "1 - SIM\n"
             << "0 - NAO\n";
        cin >> op;
    }
    for (const auto &ficha : fichario) std::cout << ficha.first << " => " << ficha.second.Cpf << '\n';
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kY5UuU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wjnnrzoq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/MapData.cpp).

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal vou anotar as dicas e estudar o map e o smart pointer ainda nao conhecia os dois, ajudou muito.