# Tipo de campo adequado para guardar moeda no Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, tipagem

Tem algum problema em salvar dados com vírgulas ou ponto (.) no meu banco de dados (SQL Developer)? Qual é a variável mais adequada para se declarar para campos do tipo moeda (preço)?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode gravar qualquer dado no banco de dados, depende do que deseja.

O tipo de coluna mais correto para guardar dinheiro é um [`NUMBER` com casas fixas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209) (há alternativas). Exemplo:

```
NUMBER(19, 4)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/Currency.sql).

Isso permite 19 dígitos com 4 na parte decimal.

[Cuidado para não usar tipo errado e ter prejuízos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Comment: Ok .Mais uma dúvida. Eu fiz uns insert, e percebi que se eu colocar 22,00; ele "exclui" os dois zeros, ficando 22. É normal? Tem alguma maneira de evitar isso?

Comment: Depende do que fez, mas se está querendo guardar dinheiro não é normal, deve ter feito algo errado. Talvez o problema seja a vírgula. tem que ser ponto. mesmo assim ambos vão armazenar 22, nada mais, a apresentação pode ser feita de várias maneiras, o problema talvez esteja aí.

Comment: Ok. Uma última dúvida(desculpa estar abusando). Em meu projeto c#, eu salvo os campos preços com a vírgula, porém, ele envia ao banco sem a vírgula. Eu tenho que fazer algum tipo de declaração?

Comment: É difícil responder coisas abstratas assim, na verdade nem sei o que está perguntando. Faça uma pergunta dando detalhes, mostrando que está fazendo, o que espera, o que está ocorrendo errado.

Comment: ok, Vou fazer e mostrar os códigos.

Answer (score 1):

Para declarar campos do tipo moeda é melhor você usar um Decimal/Numeric assim você pode definir as casas decimais.

Já para o campo com virgulas ou ponto você tem que ver o tamanho do campo, se for um texto maior você deve usar um campo do tipo Blob, se não pode utilizar um varchar. Só que você devera ter muito cuidado na hora de realizar as queries.