# Como inserir valor float por arraylist - C#?

Tags: c#

Olá, não consigo passar um valor flutuante (preço) por arraylist para o banco . Gostaria de saber se eu preciso converter antes de passar ou se existe algum modo de fazer direto. 
Já pesquisei aqui no Stack , mas não encontrei nada parecido.
Segue o código que estou estudando :

```
public bool Insert(ArrayList p_arrInsert)

  {  

vsql = "INSERT INTO tb_produtos ([PROD_NOME],[PROD_TIPO],PROD_DESCRICAO],[PROD_PRECO]) VALUES (@PROD_NOME, @PROD_TIPO, @PROD_DESCRICAO, @PROD_PRECO)";

            SqlCommand objcmd = null;


            if (this.conectar())
            {

                try
                {
                    objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROD_NOME", p_arrInsert[0]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROD_TIPO", p_arrInsert[1]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROD_DESCRICAO", p_arrInsert[2]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROD_PRECO", p_arrInsert[3]));

                    objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return true;

                }
                catch (SqlException sqlerr)
                {
                    throw sqlerr;
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.desconectar();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Eu recebo os dados através de um botão :

```
 private void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sisDBADM_PRODUTOS obj = new sisDBADM_PRODUTOS();
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                arr.Add(tbCad_nome.Text);
                arr.Add(cbTipo.Text);
                arr.Add(tbCad_nome.Text);
                arr.Add(tbCad_descricao.Text);
                arr.Add(tbCad_preco.Text);

                if (obj.Insert(arr))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Produto cadastrado com sucesso!", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    tbCad_codigo.Text = "";
                    tbCad_nome.Text = "";
                    tbCad_descricao.Text = "";
                    tbCad_preco.Text = "";


                    dgProdutos.DataSource = obj.ListaGrid(); //recarrega o datagrid

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro ao cadastrar o produto", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erro + "Erro Ocorrido!");

            }
        }
```

Eu recebo o erro :
Erro ao converter tipo de dados nvarchar em float....

Comment: Precisa de conversão ... como está indo o valor do preço?

Comment: Já vejo alguns problemas. `ArrayList` está deprecado, prefira usar `List`. O fato de dados heterogêneos virem em um *array* e não em uma classe já mostra outro problema. Na verdade acho que se fizesse do jeito correto nem precisar desse `ArrayList`. Não pode usar `float` para valor monetário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101. Está capturando exceção e fazendo nada, isto é um erro. Se é para fazer nada, não capture a exceção, mesmo que você solucione o que deseja, o sistema estará gerando valores errados, às vezes, o que é pior porque você achará que está certo. É um problema grave.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dias

Comment: @Paulo.Pasiam conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Estou trabalhando com access e salvo os valores decimais numa coluna em texto (Exemplos: 21275 | 47404,95 | 66295,9), faço o tratamento para exibição através do string.Format e para manipular no sistema utilizo uma propriedade do tipo decimal?.

Outra coisa que pode fazer é alterar o modo de popular o parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ((object)pendencia.StatusId) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FollowUp", OleDbType.Date).Value = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pendencia.FollowUp) ? DBNull.Value : (((object)pendencia.FollowUp) ?? DBNull.Value));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocumentoTipo", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ((object)pendencia.DocumentoTipo) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsCritico", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = ((object)pendencia.IsCritico) ?? DBNull.Value;
```