# Conversão Valor Monetário para Double

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte valor em Double: 1000.0

Usando o comando:
`string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", 1000.0);`

tenho a saída: R$ 1.000,00

Minha Dúvida é, como converter R$ 1.000,00 para double, ou seja, obter a saída 1000.0

Comment: E porque você faria essa conversão? Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor porquê você converte o valor no tipo double para string e depois precisa convertê-lo de novo para double?

Comment: Imagine uma tela de vendas que exista um TextBox chamado "Desconto". Este campo "Desconto" possui valores como R$ 1.000,00, onde o usuário digita manualmente.
Após essa digitação, faço o calculo Qtd x Valor Unitário - Desconto para obter o valor Total, por isso quero converter o monetário para Double.

Answer (score -1):

Se vc está utilizando para exibição vc pode colocar como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor Fator" Binding="{Binding PendenciaValorFator, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False">
```

Acredito que vc esteja fazendo o stringFormat e atribuindo a uma propriedade para mostrar na tela, quando o que vc tem que fazer é utilizar o stringFormat na exibição, assim sua propriedade com o valor 1000.0 não sofrerá alterações.

Comment: Então, minha propriedade já se inicia com os valores "R$ 1.000,00" pois é um valor digitado pelo usuário.

Comment: o usuário digita "R$"? Se sim, uma das opções é alterar a forma de uso do sistema para ele digitar somente o valor, ou se não for possível vc pode fazer Convert.ToDecimal(texto.Replace("R$ ", "")), algo do tipo... Lembrando que isso estará suscetível a uma grande gama de possíveis erros.

Comment: Também encontrei no SO-En essa solução: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162357/convert-currency-string-to-decimal

Comment: Pode utilizar:
decimal.Parse(input, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number);

ou:
decimal.Parse(Regex.Match(input, @"-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?").Value);

Comment: Entendi, vou tratar para que o usuário não digite "R$", e sim apenas números e vírgula, assim ele digitaria 1000,00 e eu uso o método Convert.toDouble.

Comment: Coloca apenas uma label ao lado do campo de texto com o conteúdo "R$" para indicar que se trata de valor monetário.

Depois não esqueça de fazer as devidas validações para o usuário não inserir texto no valor.

Agradeceria se marcasse como resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @LucasDuzo conseguiu resolver seu problema?