# Variavel tipo float não recebe valoração

Tags: c, c++

Segue um trecho do código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MVAIN  0.8592;
#define MVAOUT 1.0282;
#define ICMS 0.29;

float ProdValue = 0, MVA = 0, ResultValue1 = 0, ResultValue2 = 0, ResultValue3 = 0;

int main(){
    printf("Indique o valor dos produtos da nfe que contenham ST \n");
    scanf ("%f", &ProdValue);   

    printf ("O valor dos produtos é:  %f \n ", &ProdValue);


    printf ("Informe se o MVA é fora ou dentro do estado \n");
    scanf ("%f", &MVA) ;


if(MVA == 1) {
    ResultValue1 =  ProdValue*MVAIN; //926,23
    ResultValue2 =  ResultValue1+ProdValue; //2004,25

    ResultValue3 =  ResultValue2*ICMS; //581,23
    ResultValue2 =  ResultValue1-ResultValue2; //345,00

    printf ("O valor a recolher é %0.2f \n", ResultValue2);


    } if (MVA == 2) {
        ResultValue1 =  ProdValue*MVAOUT; //926,23
        ResultValue2 =  ResultValue1+ProdValue; //2004,25

        ResultValue3 =  ResultValue2*ICMS; //581,23
        ResultValue2 =  ResultValue1-ResultValue2; //345,00


        printf ("O valor a recolher é %0.2f \n", ResultValue2);
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? Note que valor monetário não pode ser `float`  mas não acho que este seja o problema. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101. Este código nem compila. Que valor deve entrar para testar?

Comment: Ele até compila, na verdade falta o trecho do código, note que ele termina em um "printf", eu tenho o exe dele aqui, no entanto os valores float não recebem o valor estipulado, por exemplo 1078.02. Quanto tento atribuir este valor ele não recebe. Tentei imprimir na tela os valores no entanto continuam zerados mesmo após as atribuições, isso para atribuição por entrada quanto direta.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Em um bom compilador o código nem compila. Se compilar é pior porque o código está cheio d erros. Nem vou falar no fato de [armazenar valor monetário com `float` ser um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101). O código é confuso, complicado demais e tem erro de lógica. Eu melhorei, mas não está bom ainda. Não ficou muito claro o erro, após eu corrigir os erros que impediam a compilação nenhum erro aconteceu.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MVAIN  0.8592f
#define MVAOUT 1.0282f
#define ICMS 0.29f

int main(){
    printf("Indique o valor dos produtos da nfe que contenham ST\n");
    float ProdValue = 0;
    scanf("%f", &ProdValue);   
    printf("O valor dos produtos é: %0.2f\n", ProdValue);
    printf("Informe se o MVA é fora ou dentro do estado\n");
    int MVA = 0;
    scanf("%d", &MVA);
    float ValorMVA = ProdValue * (MVA == 2 ? MVAOUT : MVAIN);
    printf ("O valor do MVA é %0.2f\n", ValorMVA);
    float ValorComMVA = ProdValue + ValorMVA;
    printf ("O valor total é %0.2f\n", ValorComMVA);
    float ValorIcms = ValorComMVA * ICMS;
    printf ("O valor do ICMS é %0.2f\n", ValorIcms);
    float Diferenca = ValorMVA - ValorIcms;
    printf ("O valor a recolher é %0.2f\n", Diferenca);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ckVsHc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/swchcgup-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Icms.c).

Comment: Boa noite, descobri onde estava o erro, estou utilizando o DEVC++, ainda não sei como definir se um compilador é bom ou ruim pois tenho pouca prática nisso, no entanto o erro realmente estava nas variáveis Float, ao muda-las para double consegui armazena-las de maneira manual. No entanto ele continuou da mesma forma sem salvar as entradas pelo scanf, como estava utilizando uma variável double eu teria que utilizar "%lf". Agora esta correto o cálculo. Obrigado e desculpe ocupar seu tempo, acabei nem utilizando o seu código.

Comment: O Dev-C++ é uma bomba, eu já sabia que estava usando ele. Mudar pra `double` não é para resolver o problema de fato, na verdade valor monetário não pode usar `double`.