# Como representar o tipo Real no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tipagem

Tenho uma tabela já existente em um banco de um cliente meu e lá tem um atributo com o tipo de dado `REAL`. Como eu represento no C#? `float` ou `decimal`? Qual o melhor caminho?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende do conteúdo. Depende se deseja exatidão de valores.

Quase sempre eu vou de `decimal` que dá a exatidão, ele é útil para valores monetários ou outros típicos que a unidade exata é importante, isto vale para vários tipos de medidas. Mas o banco de dados precisaria estar com um tipo compatível.

Mas pode ir de `double`, eventualmente `float`. Se no banco de dados está como `REAL`, deve ser o mais adequado, a semântica do tipo real é de ponto flutuante como esses tipos do C#.

O que pode se perguntar é se o banco de dados está errado e já causando problema para o sistema.

Veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essa informação eu não tenho, o que passa que é para juros, comissões e eu achei mais adequado o uso do decimal, mas pode ser que aja alguma outra informação que eu não conheço.

Comment: Se é para isto o certo é `decimal`,m as precisa estar assim no banco de dados também.

Comment: Se é para juros está errado, está causando prejuízos para a empresa, seja de valores, seja de imagem.

Comment: Não entendi, big. Como assim prejuízo? Então qual tipo eu represento no C# o REAL do Sql Server?

Comment: O problema é que o banco de dados está errado, se é juros, esquece esse `real`, isto está errado, provavelmente todo o sistema está errado. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valor-monet%c3%a1rio?sort=votes&pageSize=50. Boa parte dos sistemas existentes estão causando prejuízos por aí, incluindo gerando multas de fiscalização porque os valores ficam errados.

Comment: Entendi agora, em realidade o banco deles é estranho, mas eu estou apenas criando um aplicativo mobile e essa etapa faz parte do rest que vai viabilizar o aplicativo. O campo hora e data deles é float, por exemplo, mas não tenho como alterar isso, já existe há uns 8 anos assim e quero só fazer meu App pra eles, vender, receber e negociar outras demandas. De qualquer forma, vou levar seu comentário pra eles e deixá-los tomarem suas próprias decisões. Vou usar o decimal, pois o C# não tem o Real, para campos monetários. Valeu.

Comment: É, está tudo com problemas, aprenda a fazer certo, mas este parece ser um caso perdido. Pelo menos sua parte ficará certa para outros bancos de dados.