# Configura campo de valor monetário corretamente no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Estou tendo problemas com valor monetário em minha aplicação Asp.Net MVC e gostaria de saber como faço para configurar

Na classe

```
[Display(Name = "Valor Produto")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public float AnuncioValorProduto { get; set; }
```

Na View troquei para TexBoxFor

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnuncioValorProduto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AnuncioValorProduto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnuncioValorProduto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiz o downloads do script
[jquery-maskmoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/)

Coloquei os scripts na pasta e adicionei no BunddleConfig.cs

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.js"));
```

E esta dando o seguinte erro conforme imagem abaixo
[image: Erro campo monetário]

E inicializei o comapo com jquery conforme documentação

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#AnuncioValorProduto').maskMoney();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O primeiro problema, e bem grave, é usar `float` para valor monetário. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230639/101

Comment: @Maniero já troquei para decimal, agora o que devo fazer para continuar a configuração, pois percebo que esta invertido (,) e (.)