# Como modelar a tabela produtos para um e-commerce?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, modelagem

Estou com uma dúvida sobre como modelar a tabela `Produto` de um pequeno e-commerce q estou fazendo. Andei vendo alguns e-commerces e me deparei com a seguinte situação: mm mesmo produto pode ter cores e tamanhos diferentes, então quando o cliente escolhe o produto em uma cor diferente o sistema puxa o mesmo produto mas com cor diferente e tamanho disponível, sendo assim, aparentemente o produto é cadastrado mais de 1x com o mesmo nome, porém, cores e tamanhos diferentes, até mesmo pq o código do produto é sempre diferente, ou seja, o mesmo produto pode ter vários códigos, tamanhos, cores diferentes mas o nome é sempre o mesmo, e acredito que esse seja o pulo do gato, me corrijam se estou errado.

Seguindo essa lógica, estou tentando modelar minha classe de `Produto` desta maneira, mas me deparei com um impasse no estoque, pois o produto pode ter o mesmo nome, códigos diferentes, cores diferentes, tamanhos diferentes, mas gerenciar o estoque a partir do tamanho se torna meio complicado, pois o mesmo produto pode ter tamanhos diferentes no estoque e na hora de dar a saída do estoque eu preciso contar com essa situação. Por isso queria saber qual a melhor maneira para fazer isso?

**Tabela produto.**

```
[Serializable]
public class Produto{

    public virtual long id                                      { get; set; }
    public virtual String descricao                             { get; set; }
    public virtual String descDetalhada                         { get; set; }    
    public virtual Subcategoria subcategoria                    { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cor> cores                             { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tamanho> tamanhos                      { get; set; }
    public virtual int qtdEstoque                               { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal precoAntigo                           { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal precoReal                             { get; set; }
    public virtual int status                                   { get; set; }

    public Produto(){
        cores = new List<Cor>();
        tamanhos = new List<Tamanho>();
    }
    public override string ToString(){
        return descricao;
    }

}
```

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 6):

Já vou começar que ainda está longe de ter um modelo ideal, por exemplo [usar `double` para armazenar preço é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). Criar um software de exercício é fácil, criar um real é bem mais difícil, você vai se deparar com um monte de situação inesperada. Chega ser um paradoxo porque para começar bem precisa conceituar tudo certo, ainda mais que não tem experiência para fazer tudo o que precisa, mas sem experiência não consegue conceituar certo.

Uma forma é realmente ter produtos diferentes. É simples em um ponto complicado em outro. Precisa ver como vai querer trabalhar a apresentar. Eu prefiro a forma mais conceitualmente certa, ou seja, você tem um produto com SKUs, em em uma tabla tem o cadastro do produto e e outra tem o cadastro das variações.

O produto tem todas as características gerais do produto e isto é usado para apresentar. Na tabelas de SKUs tem o controle do estoque efetivamente porque tem que controlar cada variação. Note que se algum SKU tiver preço diferente, em geral você tem um produto diferente. Mas a decisão pode ser um pouco mais complicada. Tem caso que pode ser útil ter uma terceira tabela para grupos de SKUs. Ou pode ser que cada SKU tenha um preço diferente, aí pode ser que o preço já possa estar no SKU. Ou pode até considerar que cada SKU é um produto diferente.

É mais complicado ainda porque tem produtos que se encaixam em um modelo e outros produtos se encaixam em outro modelo.

Se está fazendo algo sem conhecer o modelo, tem que deixar ele o mais aberto possível, que atenda todas situações. E lidar com essas questões no código. Aplicações flexíveis são mais complicadas de desenvolver.

Se conhece o modelo, precisa analisar a necessidade. Pelo que li, mas pode estar errado me parece que ter uma relação 1:N em uma tabela de produto X SKU parece adequado. Assim trabalhará com produto único mas controle de estoque variado.

Talvez seja o caso de começar simples e depois repensar essa dificuldade, até ter mais subsídios para tomar uma decisão. Isto é importante porque está com dificuldades em decisões bem mais básicas. Comece pelo alicerce, deixe o acabamento para depois.

Também poderá fazer uma pergunta mais específica aqui quando tiver algo mais próximo da necessidade.

Comment: bom, pelo que entendi vc diz para criar 2 tabelas, uma do produto em si e outra do SKU. Eu costumo fazer assim para sistemas de PDV para mercados, mas no caso esse que estou fazendo não queria nada tão elaborado, até mesmo pq vou vender pouca coisa. Mas blz, entendi seu ponto de vista. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom, aí você pode fazer do jeito que quiser, a pergunta era sobre como modelar corretamente. Se você já tem uma visão de como fazer a pergunta perde o sentido. Se quer uma tabela faz um produto por SKU.

Comment: Na vdd minha duvida era mais sobre como fazer o esquema de buscar o msm produto por cores diferentes e tamanhos diferentes, como falei que ja havia visto em alguns e-commerces, pq aparentemente eles cadastram o produto várias vezes com o msm nome, porem, cores e tamanhos diferentes e como gerenciam o estoque com tantas nuances do msm produto baseado no tamanho, mas entendi seu ponto, vou tentar elaborar aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: Pra mim isso é gambiarra, embora possa ser feito. Eu prefiro o conceito mais correto. Eu desenvolvi um ERP famoso onde adotaram essa estratégia de em outra parte do sistema e até hoje é só dor de cabeça por causa da decisão errada. Mas seu caso parece que não terá tanto isso, só fique ciente que poderá ter problemas. Só lembrando que esse erro é pequeno perto de outros erros que já dá para ver nesse software.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema não é modelar tabela, e sim vc não conhece do negócio que está criando. Converse mais com seu P.O. ou seu cliente sobre todos os processos.

Só para esclarecer um pouco:

**Produto**, também conhecido como **Modelo** ou **PartNumber** é onde ficarão as características. Esse cara possui **Versões**, com características simples mudando - como cor, por exemplo. Depois vc tem o **Estoque**, onde diz qual a quantidade de cada Modelo/Versão vc possui.

Conheça mais do negócio antes de iniciar seu sistema, e leia sobre estratégias ***Code First*** antes de "modelar tabela". Repositório e persistência deve ser a ultima preocupações do desenvolvedor.

Comment: O negócio é meu mesmo, eu estou desenvolvendo para uma lojinha que tenho, mas nunca desenvolvi antes um e-commerce, por isso minha dúvida.

Comment: Não, Fernando, o negócio é da "lojinha". Vc está apenas informatizando o negócio dela.

Comment: Eu entendi sua dica: Vc diz para criar 2 tabelas, 1 para informações básicas do produto e outra para o Estoque, na tabela de estoque que irei definir tamanho, cores, etc..etc..etc. Bom, acho que é isso, eu faço assim em sistemas de PDV, porém, como o e-commerce que estou fazendo é relativamente pqno pensei em fz tbm as coisas mais simples. Mas, entendi sua dica.