# Inserção de dados numéricos no banco de dados

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, formatação, decimal

Estou tendo problemas para inserir no banco de dados o campo está formatado como `DECIMAL(10,2)`), quando tento inserir o valor monetário direto pelo MySQL funciona com o ponto final ao invés da vírgula ex:

135.45 -  O banco intende as duas casas decimais.

Agora quando tento inserir pelo meu programa, grava no bando da seguinte forma:

13545.00

Segue meu modelo.cs para esse campo

```
class Modelo
{
 private float nValor;

  public float Valor

        {
            get { return nValor; }
            set { nValor = value; }
        }
}
```

A ação do botão para gravar o valor digitado está assim:

```
private void btn_cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Modelo mo = new Modelo();
            conexao con = new conexao();

            try
            {


                if (cbox_pagamento.SelectedItem.ToString() == "a vista")
                {
                    mo.Data_Compra = txt_dcompra.Text;
                    mo.Data_Alvo = txt_dalvo.Text;
                    mo.Fornecedor = txt_fornecedor.Text;
                    mo.Valor = float.Parse(txt_valor.Text);
                    mo.Tipo = cbox_tipo.Text;
                    mo.Pagamento = lbl_fiado.Text;
                    mo.Data_Pagamento = txt_dpagamento.Text;

                    con.cadastro(mo);

                    txt_fornecedor.Text = "";
                    txt_valor.Text = "";
                    MessageBox.Show("Dados gravados com sucesso!");
                }
                else
                {
                    mo.Data_Compra = txt_dcompra.Text;
                    mo.Data_Alvo = txt_dalvo.Text;
                    mo.Fornecedor = txt_fornecedor.Text;
                    mo.Valor = float.Parse(txt_valor.Text);
                    mo.Tipo = cbox_tipo.Text;
                    mo.Pagamento = lbl_fiado.Text;
                    mo.Data_Pagamento = txt_dpagamento.Text;

                    con.cadastro_aprazo(mo);

                    txt_fornecedor.Text = "";
                    txt_valor.Text = "";
                    MessageBox.Show("Dados gravados com sucesso!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha ao salvar no banco de dados :" + ex);
            }


        }
```

Alguém tem ideia de como eu faço para inserir no banco o valor corretamente?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pode ser por causa de virgulas no seu campo, que não são identificadas na conversão. Tente alterar a linha

`mo.Valor = float.Parse(txt_valor.Text);`

por

`mo.Valor = float.Parse(txt_valor.Text.Replace(',','.'));`

Comment: Também tentei dessa maneira mais o problema está na hora que insere os dados via sistema no banco, exemplo: quando informo no sistema o valor 135,15 ou 135.15 ele insere no banco e fica dessa maneira 13515.00. Não sei mais o que fazer :(

Comment: Depois de muito pesquisar eu descobri como fazer para converter,
1º no seu banco terá que colocar o campo valor como Decimal(10,2)
2º na hora que vc for dar o Insert into vc tem que substituir a virgula pelo ponto. Fica mais ou menos assim 

string valor = textboxvalor.text;
valor = valor.replace(',','.');

O insert ficará assim: INSERT INTO TABELA(nome_coluna)values('"+valor+"');

Lembrando que uso o Visual Studio 2017 pode ser que mude um pouco se usar outro software

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que precisa mudar é o tipo correto no código. Começou fazendo bem no banco de dados, mantenha isto no código:

```
public class Modelo {
    public float Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Aí faça isto:

```
private void btn_cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var mo = new Modelo();
    var con = new conexao(); //espero que esteja bem feito para não dar vazamento
    try {
        if (Decimal.TryParse(txt_valor.Text.Replace(',', '.'), out var valor) {
            mo.Data_Compra = txt_dcompra.Text;
            mo.Data_Alvo = txt_dalvo.Text;
            mo.Fornecedor = txt_fornecedor.Text;
            mo.Valor = valor;
            mo.Tipo = cbox_tipo.Text;
            mo.Pagamento = lbl_fiado.Text;
            mo.Data_Pagamento = txt_dpagamento.Text;
            con.cadastro(mo);
            txt_fornecedor.Text = "";
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            //aqui precisa fazer a gravação
            MessageBox.Show("Dados gravados com sucesso!");
    } catch (MySqlException ex) { //capture uma exceção mais específica
        MessageBox.Show("Falha ao salvar no banco de dados :" + ex);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ConvertMoney.cs).

Note que eu capturei a exceção mais específica que é o correto. Mas não sei se a conexão não ficará pendurada aí. Eu acho que vai, mas só com este trecho não tenho como falar. Tem que corrigir isso.

Eliminei o `if` que fazia a mesma coisa. Mas coloquei outro para [pegar um erro de digitação do valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). E fiz com `decimal` que é o [tipo correto para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Fiz a inversão manual de ponto e vírgula, mas isto não é o mais correto, é melhor usar cultura. Se tiver interesse posso mostrar desta forma que é um pouco mais avançado, mas é menos gambiarra.

Comment: Fiz da forma que propôs mas o problema ocorreu da mesma forma, Quando informo o valor no sistema 135,15 ou 135.15 ele insere no banco 13515.00 não sei o motivo. sabe como posso tentar resolver isso ?

Comment: Então você precisa dar mais detalhes de como está seu código, como estão os dados. Começando por dizer qual é o problema. Talvez seja s[o o caso de dividir por 100.

Comment: Vou publicar meu código inteiro para dar uma olhada, https://pastebin.com/3CV5pK3Q - Formulário de Compra   https://pastebin.com/tpPgT06t - Modelo do projeto  https://pastebin.com/tAABv1Xe - Conexão do Projeto

Comment: Depois eu tento dar uma olhada, mas este código é todo cheio de repetições e outras coisas esquisitas. Eu se fosse você procuraria aprender o básico antes de tentar fazer algo sofisticado.

Comment: Eu tento aprender fazendo na pratica, pegando dicas e aplicando, vendo tutoriais e etc. Porém sou muito noob me perdoe

Comment: Mas parece estar no caminho bem errado, tem uma quantidade enorme de problemas nesses código. Em geral ir sem rumo assim não costuma dar certo, não conheço ninguém que aprendeu programar assim. Tem que fazer de forma estruturada, talvez com acompanhamento de quem entenda do assunto. O que mais tem na internet é gente que não sabe ensinando errado.

Comment: Você tem alguém que possa me indicar que tenha pagina na internet ou mesmo no youtube ?

Comment: Esses códigos ai são de um controle de contas a pagar está tudo funcionando perfeitamente o unico problema que descobri foi esse do valor, mas te entendo deve ter muita coisa desnecessária e repetida mais isso é pratica

Comment: Existe uma grande diferença entre funcionar e estar certo . Eu não chamaria de perfeitamente. Dá para ver pelo código que tem vários erros. Tem problemas de de validação e entrada de dados, tem cálculos que gerarão erros de arredondamento, tem tratamento errado de exceção, repetição e outras coisas que eu nem consegui entender porque está ali, só o que me lembro. Mas se você que está começando acha que está tudo perfeito e o errado sou eu que tenho 35 anos de experiência, ai não posso ajudar muito.

Comment: eu não estou falando em momento algum que você está errado, apenas vim ao fórum procurar ajuda para um problema e não aguem que me desmotivasse, vou continuar estudando e vou rever melhor os métodos de ensino. Porém queria saber o motivo que não está funcionando, motivo ao qual ainda não descobri. De qualquer forma você já me ajudou.

Comment: Estou te motivando fazer o certo, se escolher o caminho errado você se desmotivará quando perceber que tudo está desmoronando e não era do jeito que estava pensando. Se der tempo eu vejo mais.

Comment: Tudo certo amigo, eu infelizmente fui fazendo tudo na gambiarra e só agora foi dar esse problema e não consegui resolver. mas sem pressa quando tiver um tempinho e puder dar uma olhada eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Manda imprimir o valor digitado antes de converter ou salvar no banco.

Comment: Me desculpe pela ignorância mas não entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito pesquisar eu descobri como fazer para converter,
1º no seu banco terá que colocar o campo valor como Decimal(10,2)
2º na hora que vc for dar o Insert into vc tem que substituir a virgula pelo ponto. Fica mais ou menos assim

string valor = textboxvalor.text;
valor = valor.replace(',','.');

O insert ficará assim: INSERT INTO TABELA(nome_coluna)values('"+valor+"');

Lembrando que uso o Visual Studio 2017 pode ser que mude um pouco se usar outro software