# Struct apresentando problema

Tags: c++, struct

Não estou conseguindo compilar o programa apresenta erro na declaração da variável `struct` produto, quando tento criar uma instancia na `main`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct produto;

int main() {
    produto prod1={"Caneca",5.00}; // Ao compilar apresenta erro nessa linha.
    cout<<"Nome do Produto: \n";
    cin>>prod1.nome;
    cout<<"Valor de venda: \n";
    cin>>prod1.valorvenda;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


struct produto{
    char nome[21];
    float valorvenda;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a estrutura antes de usá-la.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct produto {
    char nome[21];
    float valorvenda;
};

int main() {
    produto prod1 = { "Caneca", 5.00 };
    cout << "Nome do Produto: \n";
    cin >> prod1.nome;
    cout << "Valor de venda: \n";
    cin >> prod1.valorvenda;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MvbYDl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zmuztvbe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/StructDeclaration.cpp).

Pra um exercício assim está ok usar [`float` para dinheiro, mas não faça isto em aplicações reais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Comment: Ótima referência