# Gravação em campo float no sql server com c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Bom dia, estou fazer um update em um campo float no sql server, mas não estou conseguindo esta dando dum erro de conversão, ja tentei varias formas e não obtive sucesso, sigo recebendo este retorno de erro =  Error converting data type varchar to float.

segue meu código.

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "update tbl_Produto set Lote = '" + cb_lote.Text + "', Qtda = CONVERT(FLOAT, '" + txt_qtda.Text + "') where  Cod_Produto = '" + txt_codigo.Text + "'";
            cmd.Connection = conex1;

            conex1.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conex1.Close();
```

Comment: Onde está dando tal erro ?

Comment: estou recebendo este erro Error converting data type varchar to float. quando vou fazer o update este campo Qtda = CONVERT(FLOAT, '" + txt_qtda.Text + "') na minha query. O erro aparece no moamento da execução da query cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Tem certeza que usurá `float` para isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101 E se o usuário digitar algo errado, a aplicação quebra?

Comment: Bom provavelmente é aqui  Qtda = CONVERT(FLOAT, '" + txt_qtda.Text + "')

Comment: o que tem em `txt_qtda.Text`? Talvez o problema seja de formatação: `select CONVERT(float, '0.123')` funciona. (checa se o valor não está com vírgula)

Comment: Mas e um campo de quantidade em kg então tem que ser desta forma.

Comment: txt_qtda.Text recebe valores me Kilogramas. Ex. 0,200 ou 0,05 valores assim

Comment: Isso mesmo o valor e colocado com virgula no campo.

Comment: eu usei um replace par trocar a virgula por ponto e funcionou, mas o valor que era pra ser 0,200 ele gravou 200 no banco.

Comment: nesse código da pra fazer sql injection

Comment: Ok problema resolvido estava colocando a virgula. Troquei por ponto e funcionou, gravou certinho, na hora de digitar o valor, eu digitei com ponto e ele gravou certinho no banco.Vacilo de principiante..kkk. Mas muito obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Funcionar é diferente de estar certo.

Comment: Então concordo sim, agora só preciso fazer com que o campo só aceite ponto e não aceite virgula, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta passar por parâmetro, algo parecido com isso:

```
string sqlQuery = "update tbl_Produto set Lote=@lote, Qtda=@qtda where Cod_Produto=@codigo";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conex1);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lote", txt_qtda.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@qtda", SqlDbType.Float);
cmd.Parameters["@qtda"].Value = (float) Convert.ToDouble(cb_lote.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@codigo"].Value = int.Parse(cb_lote.Text);

conex1.Open();
Int32 linhasResultado = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Isto é uma boa ideia, mas o problema mesmo é outros, ou outros, tem vários neste código e eles ainda estão presentes no seu, que introduz novos erros.

Comment: Valeu muito obrigado pela ajuda.