# Erro ao converter campo varchar em float

Tags: sql

Estou gerando uma Query e nessa Query estou fazendo um join entre um campo `varchar` e um campo `float`.

Sendo o campo `SY.YE_MOEDA` é `varchar` e o campo `DA1_A1_MOEDA` é `float`.

Segue minha Query:

```
SELECT
DA.DA1_CODTAB  AS TABELA,
DA.DA1_CODPRO  AS CODPRODUTO,
SB.B1_DESC     AS DESCRICAO,
SB.B1_PRV1     AS PRECOVENDA,
DA.DA1_MOEDA   AS MOEDA,
SY.YE_MOEDA    AS NOMEMOEDA
FROM DA1010 AS DA
INNER JOIN SB1010 AS SB WITH (NOLOCK) ON SB.B1_COD = DA.DA1_CODPRO
INNER JOIN SYE010 AS SY WITH (NOLOCK) ON CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(SY.YE_MOEDA,0)) = DA.DA1_MOEDA
WHERE DA.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND DA.DA1_ATIVO = '1'
```

Segue o erro

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar
>   to float.

Comment: Isto é o Protheus?

Comment: Sim protheus, mas consegui resolver o problema, na tabela onde esta o valor da moeda tinha um campo escondido com o código da moeda do tipo float, e este campo resolveu o problema do join.Mas muito obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Moeda `float` é muito errado. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101

Answer (score -1):

No oracle existe um truque para fazer esta conversão:

```
select meuCampo + 0.0 as comoFloat from minhaTabela
```

Suponho que funcione no sql serve.

Outra solução é trocar o convert para decimal, ficando:

```
SELECT
DA.DA1_CODTAB  AS TABELA,
DA.DA1_CODPRO  AS CODPRODUTO,
SB.B1_DESC     AS DESCRICAO,
SB.B1_PRV1     AS PRECOVENDA,
DA.DA1_MOEDA   AS MOEDA,
SY.YE_MOEDA    AS NOMEMOEDA
FROM DA1010 AS DA
INNER JOIN SB1010 AS SB WITH (NOLOCK) ON SB.B1_COD = DA.DA1_CODPRO
INNER JOIN SYE010 AS SY WITH (NOLOCK) ON CONVERT(DECIMAL, ISNULL(SY.YE_MOEDA,0)) = DA.DA1_MOEDA
WHERE DA.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND DA.DA1_ATIVO = '1'
```

Comment: Sim protheus, mas consegui resolver o problema, na tabela onde esta o valor da moeda tinha um campo escondido com o código da moeda do tipo float, e este campo resolveu o problema do join.Mas muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: SHOW QUE BOM :)

Comment: Tabela customizada em Protheus com "chave" numérica , você se arrepende de ter nascido .... :)