# Método não retorna boolean true mesmo sendo positivo

Tags: java, mysql

Estou com um projeto conta que faz um deposito, porem nao estou conseguindo retornar um true mesmo ele achando o valor no banco de dados

esse meu metodo da Classe conta

```
public boolean depositoConta(double deposito) {

System.out.println("Metodo de Doposito()");

boolean resultado = false;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con = this.getConexao();
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT saldo FROM conta WHERE idconta = ?");
    stmt.setInt(1, getId());
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();


    if (rs.next()) {        
        this.setSaldo(rs.getDouble("saldo"));
        saldo += deposito;
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE conta SET saldo=? WHERE idconta = ? ");
        stmt.setDouble(1, this.getSaldo());
        stmt.setInt(2, getId());
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();   
        resultado = true;

    }

    con.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Erro no método Deposito: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return resultado;
```

}

e esse e o meu metodo da classe serviçoConta, ou seja e um WebService

```
public boolean deposito(int idConta, double quantia )
{
    boolean resultado= false;
    try {
        Conta conta = new Conta();
        conta.setId(idConta);

        resultado = conta.depositoConta(quantia);       

          System.out.println((resultado == true ? "Deposito efetuado com sucesso." : "Erro ao Efeuar o Deposito" ));    

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro no serviço deposito: " + e.getMessage());
    }   

    return resultado;

}
```

esse erro o Eclipse retorna Erro no método Deposito: Nenhum resultado foi retornado pela consulta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos desmitificar algumas coisas: primeiro o Eclipse não retorna nada porque ele é [apenas um IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

O código faz coisas que não precisa, faz coisas que dão problema de condição de corrida, faz coisas que deveriam estar em outro lugar (tratamento de tela), produzirá resultados indesejados em determinadas situações de exceção e provavelmente deve ter outros problemas, sem falar que a arquitetura deve ser complicada demais para o que precisa.

E [`double` não deveria ser usado para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Também falta organização, padrão de estilo e nomenclatura.

Depois de imprimir *stack trace* não deveria continuar executando a aplicação.

```
public boolean depositoConta(double quantia) {
    System.out.println("Metodo de Doposito()"); //isto não deveria estar aqui
    try {
        Connection con = this.getConexao(); //isto não deveria ser assim
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE conta SET saldo = saldo + ? WHERE idconta = ?");
        stmt.setDouble(1, quantia);
        stmt.setInt(2, getId()); //tenho medo do que seja isto, deveria ser um parâmetro
        return stmt.executeUpdate() != 0;
    } catch (Exception e) { //isto pega qualquer erro e não apenas o que deveria
        System.out.println("Erro no método Deposito: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        con.close();
    }
}

public boolean deposito(int idConta, double quantia) { //id aqui bem melhor
    try {
        Conta conta = new Conta(idConta); //deveria poder fazer isto
        boolean executado = conta.depositoConta(quantia);
        System.out.println(executado ? "Deposito efetuado com sucesso." : "Erro ao Efeuar o Deposito" );
        return executado;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro no serviço deposito: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }   
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/Connection.java)

Fora resolver essas coisas, se o problema persistir é que o banco de dados não tem o que espera que tenha e realmente não consegue realizar a operação. Isto não temos como ajudar.