# Como definir um ponteiro como parâmetro default em C++?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, parâmetros, argumento

Estou "programando em C", mas compilando usando a extensão `.cpp` e o g++ para ter algumas facilidades. Meu objetivo é fazer um programinha que recebe um salário inicial e calcula o salário final de acordo com determinada bonificação. A bonificação é dada em porcentagem em cima do salário inicial, e caso a função seja chamada sem que seja passado um valor para a bonificação, deve-se assumir o valor de 15%.

O que eu fiz:

```
#include <cstdio>

float calculaSalario(float* salario, float* bonificacao = 15.0f);

int main (void)
{
    float salario = 0;
    float bonificacao = 0;

    scanf("%f", &salario);
    scanf("%f", &bonificacao);

    calculaSalario(&salario, &bonificacao);

    printf("%f\n", salario);

    return 0;
}

float calculaSalario(float* salario, float* bonificacao = 15.0f)
{
    *salario = *salario + *salario * (*bonificacao/100);
}
```

Porém, estou recebendo os seguintes erros:

- error: could not convert ‘1.5e+1f’ from ‘float’ to ‘float*’
  float calculaSalario(float* salario, float* bonificacao = 15.0f);
- In function ‘float calculaSalario(float*, float*)’: error: default argument given for parameter 2 of ‘float calculaSalario(float*, float*)’ [-fpermissive] note: previous specification in ‘float calculaSalario(float*, float*)’ here
  float calculaSalario(float* salario, float* bonificacao = 15.0f);

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

O primeiro problema óbvio é [usar `float` para valor monetário, não pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). Mas por um azar tremendo não gera erro, apenas causa problemas, às vezes, e o programador acha que está certo.

Outro erro é usar ponteiro nesta função, não faz sentido, principalmente porque ela já prevê retornar algo. Na verdade o que a função retorna não é o salário, então o correto nem é guardar na mesma variável, funciona e está certo, mas é mais legível e organizado guardar em uma variável que seja o salário bonificado. Não é legal reaproveitar variável para outra coisa.

```
#include <cstdio>

float calculaSalario(float salario, float bonificacao = 15.0) { return salario + salario * (bonificacao / 100); }

int main() {
    float salario = 0;
    float bonificacao = 0;
    scanf("%f", &salario);
    scanf("%f", &bonificacao);
    salario = calculaSalario(salario, bonificacao);
    printf("%f\n", salario);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/m8xGon). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qtwwaudf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/CalcSalary.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, ela realmente resolve o problema. Mas, se eu quisesse usar os ponteiros, mesmo ''não fazendo sentido'', como eu deveria prosseguir? Eu posso definir um ponteiro como parâmetro default?

Comment: O que significa essa parte?-> float calcularSalario(float salario,float bonificacao = 15.0) bonificacao recebe 15.0 antes de ser utilizado na funcao ?

Comment: @Rogi93, a função pode ser chamada sem passar nenhum valor pra "bonificacao", e caso ela seja chamada assim, a variavel bonificacao assumira como padrao o valor "15.0".

Comment: @miloski eu não consigo imaginar porque fazer uma coisa que não faz sentido. É o mesmo que dizer "eu preciso do resultado de um número dividido por 2, mas eu vou dividir por 3". Mas se for fazer não usará o valor *default*, porque o tipo passou ser outro, então, conforme o erro indica não faz sentido ter um valor `float` como *default* dele, teria que ser um endereço de memória, o que faria menos sentido ainda. Quando faz um erro, outros veem junto. Programar baseado em suposições não dá certo. E nem falei que já que está usando "facilidades" do C++ nem deveria usar o ponteiro onde pode.

Comment: @Rogi93 sim, mas se precisar de mais detalhes faça uma nova pergunta no site.