# Sair de um ciclo de chamadas de métodos

Tags: c#, recursão

Vamos imaginar a seguinte situação:

> Uma empresa tem a politica de doar 3% do seu lucro para projetos sociais, e esse valor doado deve entrar como despesa para a empresa no período.

Resumidamente temos essa situação:

[image: Descrição do problema]

Montando no Excel seria isso e é possível solucionar:

[image: Como fica no Excel]

Pra facilitar o ciclo, vamos supor que a receita é de 10.000,00 e a única despesa que existe para a empresa é com a doação.

Transformando a situação em código, seria assim:

```
double calculaDoacao() { return 0.03 * calculaLucro(); }
double calculaLucro() { return 10000 - calculaDoacao();}
```

Como solucionar este problema, visto que este ciclo é necessário?

[Referência da solução do problema no Excel](https://excelmaniacos.com/2016/12/19/dicas-quando-a-referencia-circular-e-desejada/).

Comment: Defina "retorna". Mostre o código. No seu problema você tem que ter uma condição de encerramento, se não tem é impossível resolver isto.

Comment: Ok. Vou Editar o problema pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Receita - Despesas = Lucro_Antes_Doação. Lucro_Real = Lucro_Antes_Doacao - Doação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, está usando o tipo errado para valor monetário, [veja o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). E [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Leu tudo o que está na página *linkada*? Lá mostra como configurar o Excel e mostra que depois de ligar a quebra da referência cíclica você também tem que dizer quantas iterações deseja que seja realizada. Ou seja, estabeleceu uma condição de encerramento da repetição das chamadas, então o código tem que lidar com isto. É o que quer? Fiz um exemplo, eu faria de um jeito melhor, mas não quis mudar demais o que está tentando fazer.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = new Exemplo();
        WriteLine(x.CalculaLucro());
    }
}

public class Exemplo {
    private decimal calculaDoacao(int iteracao, decimal valor) => 0.03M * calculaLucro(iteracao, valor);
    private decimal calculaLucro(int iteracao, decimal valor) {
        if (iteracao++ == 100) return valor;
        return valor - calculaDoacao(iteracao, valor);
    }
    public decimal CalculaDoacao() => calculaDoacao(0, 10000M);
    public decimal CalculaLucro() => calculaLucro(0, 10000M);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bRqEBv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLQx7N). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/LimitingRecursive.cs).

Em certo ponto a número de interações não muda o resultado final útil. Ou seja, com 100 ou com 10 o valor depois de 2 ou 4 casas decimais, como costumamos usar em valores monetários, o valor dá o mesmo. Neste caso com 5 parece já dar.